# What is the difference between a char[] and a string in c++?

Tags: c++, arrays, string, char

I am used to programming in Java and am doing something now which involves a little C++.

I am not actually learning C++, I am actually using assembly code, it is the C++ part that I have no idea about.

I have looked at past code from my lecturer (University), and to define a variable containing what I (being a Java developer) would call a String, he declared it as a char[] (I assume this means char/character array).

```
char get1[] = "Give me the first number:";
```

Does C++ use char arrays to mean Strings or are they different?

For the extremely limited C++ I am using, should I assume them to be the same and use char arrays as my lecturer does?

All I will be doing with this string is printing it to the screen as certain point (Using printf if any of you know intel x86 assembly). Should I be using char arrays?

Thank you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1287306/difference-between-string-and-char-types-in-c

Comment: What do you mean by *string*? `std::string` or `char const *str = "I am a string literal";`?

Comment: A `[const] char` array terminating with `\0` is referred to as a *C-string*. There are conversion constructors in `std::string` that take a C-string but they are not the same thing. Also, a notable difference is that the length of C-string is always one higher than the `std::string` constructed from that C-string (because of the termination character - i.e. `strlen(str) > std::string(str).size()`).

Comment: see also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1466073/how-is-stdstring-implemented

Comment: @Praetorian, a sequence of characters. I don't have a clue what std:string means but the second thing "I am a string literal" is what I am referring to.

Comment: All I will be doing with this string is printing it to the screen as certain point (Using printf if any of you know intel x86 assembly). Should I be using char arrays?

Answer (score 2):

A `std::string` is a class with functionality. A char array is just that - an array of characters.

You can colloquially call a null-terminated char array (such as your example) a C-style string, but that's just a name.

Answer (score 1):

Char arrays are certainly a kind of string - c++ programmers and API documentation often refer to char arrays as "c strings", or "c-style strings" (to differentiate them from CStrings, which are a Microsoft concept and something totally different).

One of the most annoying things about c++ as a language is that it *doesn't* define a single string concept as native to the language, exactly, so there are a number of constructs that all implement strings. std::string (or, if you use unicode, which you should, std::wstring) is the most common implementation, being cross-platform and *[basically](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++_Standard_Library)* part of the language at this point, but if you use Microsoft code you'll also see APIs that call for strings of type BSTR, _bstr_t, CComBSTR, and CString - all of these are also string types!

In general, I'd use std::[w]string if given the choice, and convert strings to (w)char-arrays as necessary - though if your string operations are pretty simple, and your output is going to have to be a c-string anyway, it wouldn't be that weird to do everything in terms of c-strings.

Comment: `std::wstring` is not unicode string. It is a string of `wchar_t` type, and `wchar_t` is only UCS-2 compliant on Windows. On Linux, a Unicode string would be `std::string`, which is usually encoded in UTF-8.