# std::string vs char array for static const

Tags: c++, arrays, static

I want to use a string constant in multiple places in my cpp file. Should I use std::string or char[]?

```
static const std::string kConstantString = "ConstantStringValue";

static const char kConstantString[] = "ConstantStringValue";
```

I was told to prefer the latter since it "avoids static allocation". Doesn't the char array also have to be statically allocated?

Comment: The main reason I would prefer `static const char[]` is to avoid the object fingerprint of `std::string`. Are you dealing with such strict limitations?

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1287306/difference-between-string-and-char-types-in-c) may help you understand.....Personally, I would use std::string.....

Comment: @101010: The, ehm, what? "Object fingerprint"? What's that, then?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I mean size with `std::string` you carry an extra size attributed to the class.

Comment: In this [demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a065257f8e51aaf2) you can see that with `std::string` you carry an extra burden of 32 bytes which is attributed to the class.`

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Oh yes! :)

Comment: @101010: Well okay then. BRB calling the bytes police

Comment: @101010 thanks for the sizeof demo. I really wanted to understand how much room one takes compared to the other. I don't think we have such strict limitations in our case, but good to know what the size tradeoff is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, yes it does also have to be statically allocated.

Always use `std::string` unless your profiler tells you that it's worth pissing around with legacy crap like `const char[]`. Choosing `const char[]` is an annoying micro-optimization over `std::string` and a stupid decision unless you know for sure that this piece of code is a hotpath (since it's static either way I highly doubt it).

Comment: Downvoted. Using `static const std::string` is a recipe for disaster because of the static initialization order fiasco, someone might inadvertely use it in other static constants. I actually saw it happens several times...

Comment: -1: No, no allocations are happening. Static `const char*` strings will get a special location in the binary (RO section). Nothing got malloc'd, it's simply "there" to be accessed. Static `std::string` does require static initialization and thus you're opening yourself up for [SIOF](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/siof), like @Synxis mentioned.

Answer (score 4):

Simply define a pointer to this string literal.:) It can have static storage specifier.

There is no any need to use class std::string. It is simply redundant and uselessly. This constant always can be converted to std::string if it is indeed required.

Comment: Aside from _all the reasons you forgot/ignored_, sure.

Answer (score 0):

Since it's a `static const`, you won't be able to do any manipulation on this string anyway, so it is better to just use `const char[]`.

Comment: What about read-only 'manipulation'? Things like getting the length or concatenating it into another string would be a lot easier if one could use the `std::string` functions rather than trudging through `strcat()` et al. Sure, if it's just a label and won't be entered into any manipulation, then maybe the `char` is fine - but let's not oversimplify (like all the other answers here...)