# A frequency function using template

Tags: c++, templates, frequency

I am trying to write a template-based function frequency that will return the count of the occurrences of an item in an array of items.

So far I have

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <class T>
T frequency(T array[], T arraySize, T item) {

    int count = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++) {
        if (array[i] == item) {
            count++;
        }
    }

    return count;

}

int main() {

    // Testing template with int
    int intArray[10] = { 1, 2, 3, 3, 14, 3, 2, 7, 99, 2 };
    cout << "{ ";
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        cout << intArray[i] << " ";
    }
    cout << "}" << endl;
    cout << "Frequency of 3: " << frequency(intArray, 10, 3) << endl;
    cout << "Frequency of 2: " << frequency(intArray, 10, 2) << endl;
    cout << "Frequency of 99: " << frequency(intArray, 10, 99) << endl;

    // Testing template with double
    double doubleArray[10] = { 1.5, 2.2, 99.4, 132.11, 1.5, 2.22, 1.515, 66.2, 51.8, 34.0 };
    cout << "{ ";
        for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
            cout << doubleArray[j] << " ";
        }
    cout << "}" << endl;
    cout << "Frequency of 1.5: " << frequency(doubleArray, 10, 1.5) << endl;
    cout << "Frequency of 2.2: " << frequency(doubleArray, 10, 2.2) << endl;
    cout << "Frequency of 100.1: " << frequency(doubleArray, 10, 100.1) << endl;


    return 0;
}
```

however, I get an error of "no matching function for call to 'frequency(double [10], int, double)'" towards when I try to print out the frequency of the doubles. I am unsure what I am doing wrong.

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 1):

`frequency` takes parameters of element of array and `arraySize` with the same type, i.e. `T`. But you pass arguments of that with different types, i.e. `double` vs `int`. Then the type deduction fails because `T` can't be deduced (determined).

According to your implemantaion, the type `arraySize` seems fixed, you can just declare it as `std::size_t` or `int`. And same for the return type. Their types won't change then shouldn't be declared with template parameters.

```
template <class T>
int frequency(T array[], std::size_t arraySize, T item) {

    int count = 0;

    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < arraySize; i++) {
        if (array[i] == item) {
            count++;
        }
    }

    return count;
}
```

Comment: Since I am passing different arguments for different arrays (double, int, and wanting to add string), how should I go about this?

Comment: @zerrisk The type of element of array will change, but the type of `arraySize` and return type doesn't change, isn't it? Then you shouldn't declare them as template parameters.

Comment: I just changed that, but a guideline for my project was to pass the arraySize into the function.

Comment: @zerrisk I'm not sure what the guideline mean, but it seems fine because you're passing it as function argument with type `std::size_t` (or you could use `int`). (Is the guideline relevant with template parameter? Or just talking about function parameter?)

Comment: Thank you, also I was able to figure out how to use string as well by adding a second "class S" in template <class T, class S>, but I'm not sure why that works.

Comment: No.  You *don't* want a second template parameter here.  Let's consider a nice simple (non-template), function that counts the occurence of a string in an array of strings:  `size_t frequency_s( std::string array[], size_t array_size, std::string item)`.  Notice how only the array and the item are declared as `std::string`?  They are the parameters you want to template.  `array_size` and the function return type are *always* going to be some sort of integer (and I would recommend `size_t` for this sort of thing - you avoid all sorts of problems with comparing unsigned and signed values).

Comment: @Martin Bonner If I'm only using 1 template parameter, I'm still not sure why integers and doubles work for it, but not strings. I have it set up as `int frequency(T array[], int arraySize, T item)`

Comment: @zerrisk Yes technically you can use multiple template parameters, it depends on how you implement it.

Comment: @zerrisk What do you mean not work for strings? How do you use it?

Comment: `string stringArray[5] = { "hello", "hello", "code", "finals", "last" };`            
`cout << "Frequency of \"hello\": " << frequency(stringArray, 5, "hello") << endl;`

Comment: @zerrisk Try `frequency(stringArray, 5, string("hello"))`. `"hello"` is not of type `std::string`, it's `const char[6]` indeed, and then leads to the same issue as I explained in my answer (the 1st paragraph).

Comment: Thank you so much! May I ask why it is considered a const char[6] and not a string type? I'm sorry, going from a Java class to this slightly confuses me with the syntax and reasoning behind it.

Comment: @zerrisk http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1287306/difference-between-string-and-char-types-in-c

Comment: @zerrisk Sure. It's just because the C++ standard says that (mostly inherited from C). See more details about [string literal](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal).

Comment: @zerrisk:  You are doing two things here:  You are passing around some random objects (in an array, and as a target), and you are counting things (total number of objects in the array, and number of times target found).  `int` and `double` are perfectly valid objects, but they can also be used to count things (although that can get a little dodgy for large numbers with double - because of variable precision).  strings on the other hand are still perfectly valid objects, but they are not nearly so good for counting.

Answer (score 0):

You should not use your template parameter with arraySize. Because you compare it with `i`, `int i = 0; i < arraySize;`. And the return type should not be T too because a double is not accurate don't use it like counter. Plus you do `return count` and you write `int count = 0;`

```
template <class T>
int frequency(T const array[], int arraySize, T const &item);
```

Be aware that the standard library has a template function to this purpose. In a production code, you should use [`std::count_if()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/count).

```
int count = std::count_if(intArray.begin(), intArray.end(), [](int i){ return i == 42; });
```

Comment: If this was real code, you wouldn't write `frequency` at all - you would write `std::count` directly.  This is *clearly* an educational exercise, and the OP will be expected to implement the body of the function themselves.

Comment: I think you should tell him about `std::count`, but to say "You should use ..." is wrong.  He shouldn't (because that doesn't meet the requirements he has).  If you had written "In production code, you should use..." then I would entirely agree.

Answer (score -1):

You can crate frequency as, so that it can be used with other containers.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

template <class outputIterator,class T>
int frequency(outputIterator b,outputIterator e ,const T& v) {

    int count = 0;

    while(b != e)
    {
        if(*b == v)
        {
            count++;
        }
        b++;
    }
    return count;

}

int main ()
{
  std::vector<int> first={1,1,2,3,4,5,5};
  std::cout<<frequency(first.begin(),first.end(),1)<<std::endl;

  int  arr[]={1,2,3,5,5,5};
  std::cout<<frequency(std::begin(arr),std::end(arr),5)<<std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: You mean `frequency(std::begin(arr), std::end(arr), 5)` - do it properly!