# How to dynamically allocate enough data from text file into a char* and copy into memory C++

Tags: c++, c++11

```
Text.txt 
Hi how 
are you 
Hey 
There

char* strings;
```

How do I dynamically allocate enough data for strings and properly and copy it into memory?

Comment: Read a good C++ book . https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list

Comment: I noticed this is for C. Isn't the syntax different?

Answer (score 0):

Use std::string. It will handle the allocation for you.

Comment: Practicing a lab at the moment for char * specifically. Is there a difference? Sorry, I'm still learning slowly.

Comment: @TheNubProgrammer: [A pretty huge difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1287306/difference-between-string-and-char-types-in-c).

Comment: @Jamal Do you know of any methods that i could do to dynamically allocate data for a char* by counting each line in the text file?

Comment: @TheNubProgrammer: using `char*` is for C. In C++, you should be using `std::string` instead. Coupled with `std::ifstream`, `std::getline()` and `std::vector`, all of the file I/O and memory management would be done for you. If you are learning C++, learn C++ properly, not C.