# Why the size of strings different in these cases?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    string str = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwy";
    cout << sizeof str << endl;
    cout<< sizeof "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwy"<<endl;
}
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
24
25
```

Why the sizes of the string are different although the number of characters are same?

Comment: Are you aware that `sizeof` is a *compile-time* operator?  Are you also aware that `sizeof` simply returns the size of the *type*, in bytes?  If you stuck a thousand characters in the `std::string`, the `sizeof` will still return 24.  [See this](https://godbolt.org/z/49TczG3Ed).

Comment: Try with a few different strings, and you will notice that `str` always has the same size. Then look up `sizeof` in your favourite C++ book.

Comment: I would also recommend using a [good c++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: for the size of a string (content) use `str.size()`. sizeof returns the size of the type not the instance. The sizeof("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwy") returns 25 because a string literal always will get an extra 0 byte at the end (to denote end of string). Where are you learning C++ from?

Comment: side note : stop using `using namespace std;` (the reasons can easily be found online)

Answer (score 3):

Because in the case of the first string, it assigned to, and therefore converted to, an `std::string` or a C++ string which is a fixed-size object that stores a reference to the allocation of the string behind the scenes. On your implementation the `sizeof` any `std::string` happens to be 24.

But when you write just `sizeof "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwy"` by itself, the string is interpreted as a C string or `char[25]`, which includes the 24 visible characters and an empty character called the null terminator character at the end.

See [Difference between string and char[] types in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1287306/16217248) and the linked duplicates for more information.