# How to set a char* dynamically (based on a conditional)

Tags: c++

I am trying to the following in C++ without using `std::string`. Here is the code I am trying to use and I would like to not use any deprecated futures.

```
void Application::_check_gl_error(const char* file, int line)
{
    GLenum err(glGetError());
    while (err != GL_NO_ERROR) {
        char* error;
        switch (err) {
            case GL_INVALID_OPERATION: 
                error = "INVALID_OPERATION";
                break;
        }

        std::cerr << "Error: " << err << " GL_" << error << " - " << file << ":" << line << std::endl;
    }
}
```

I have read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4826494/3291506) that in C++ using `char*` without `const` and pointing to a string is deprecated.

> You should also push the warning level of your compiler up a notch: then it will warn that your first code (i.e. **char* str = "name") is legal but deprecated.**

however, if I declare `const char* error` in every case, I get an error in the call to `std:cerr` that says `error: Identifier "error" is not defined`

Is there a way for be to conditionally set the value of `error` here or make it visible for the call to std::cerr?

**EDIT:**
I like the idea of returning a `const char*` however, that would require calling another function from within `check_gl_error` to print out the results.  I am hoping to avoid that step.

Comment: What's the problem really? _"In C++ char* is deprecated"_ What does that mean? _"however, if I declare const char* error in every case"_ Why do you do that, and how is it a solution to the preceding? Just use `const char*` exactly where you have it, and just assign to it. Or better, use the conditional operator or a function.

Comment: "In C++ char* is deprecated" is this true?

Comment: Create a [mcve].

Comment: `char* error;` -> `const char* error;`. Why would you declare it in every case...

Comment: @Startec:  Can you show proof that `char *` is deprecated?  Pointers are not deprecated AFAIK.

Comment: Is there a reason you are trying to avoid `std::string` if this is C++ code?

Comment: @i486 It's not true. It may be a confused form of "conversion from string literal to `char*` is deprecated", which used to be true until C++11. Since then the conversion has been ill-formed.

Comment: Plain `char*` is not deprecated, you should just not use it for string literals since they are arrays of constant characters.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews I added a reference to where I got the idea that `char*` was deprecated in C++.

Comment: is it possible that you are confusing `const char *` with `char * const` ? They are quite different...

Comment: Your code has unbalanced `{}`, so won't compile for that reason.  Fix those and you might get at the real problem...

Comment: @Startec about the clarifying quote: it says that `char* str = "name"` is deprecated. That's very different from "`char*` is deprecated". Also, the quoted answer has been outdated for a while as `char* str = "name"` is no longer legal since C++11, see my earlier comment.

Comment: @Startec the edited description is still not accurate. It's not deprecated to point to a string with `char*`. It's the implicit conversion from string literal to `char*` that is deprecated (or was deprecated and is now illegal). It's never deprecated to point to anything with any pointer. Besides, it's completely safe to point a string with `char*` or even modify a string, if that string isn't a literal or otherwise const.

Comment: @user2079303 and then also safe to point a `char*` at nothing and then change where it points?  But in this case, aren't I pointing it to a string literal?

Comment: @Startec It's always safe to change where a pointer points, as long as it doesn't violate any invariant. Yes, in this case you point to a string literal. It's not safe, to point to it with `char*` - it's quite a bad idea to do so infact - but it is not "deprecated".

Comment: @user2079303 can you briefly explain why it is a bad idea? The length of the literal is know right? How can it be unsafe?

Comment: @Startec It's unsafe because string literals are const, but `char*` has no compile time check for preventing writing to the pointed object. Attempting to write to a const object has undefined behaviour. In general, it is a bad idea to point to a const object with a pointer / reference to non-const type.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"In C++ char* is deprecated" - that's a myth that needs to be busted. A string literal is a `const char[]` type in C++, and that *decays* to a `const char*` in many instances.

Refactoring to a *function* would be absolutely fine:

```
const char* error(int err){
    switch (err){
    case 1:
        return "Case one";
    case 2:
        return "Case two";
    }
    return nullptr;
}
```

For the avoidance of doubt the string literals do **not** need to be the same length.

Answer (score 2):

The problem has nothing to do with `char *` -- the problem is that `error` is defined as local within a nested block, so it is no longer in scope after that block when you try to use it.

Move the declaration of `error` outside (before) the while loop.

Comment: Not sure about that if "counting the braces" is anything to do by: the one closing the loop is missing.

Comment: @Bathsheba: this is a best-guess, based on the error message reported -- the code as posted has unbalanced braces and won't compile.

Comment: I fixed a typo. `error` and the call to `std::cout` are both in the while loop

Comment: Are you sure that code gives you that error message?  The error message indicates that `error` has fallen out of scope (or has never been defined).

Comment: Ensure your question includes the exact code and exact error, which should quote a line and column number that corresponds to the code.

Comment: There you have `error` defined as local inside the `switch`, so it can't be used outside of it.  Had you posted that code originally, you would have had an answer almost immediately.

Answer (score 1):

```
const char* errors[] = {
    "Case one",
    "Case two"
};
std::cerr << errors[err - 1];
```

If your error numbers are not continuous and you have a lot of them, you can use `std::unordered_map`. You get O(1) access time on average.

If you have very few error codes and your error numbers are not continuous,  `std::vector` with binary search might perform better. You get O(log n) complexity but it beats the `unordered_map` for small values of `n`.

Comment: [complete speculation based on hazy memories of performance comparisons] Might an ordered `map` be better for relatively small sets with numerical keys?

Comment: Why would you use `std::map` over `std::vector` when both provide O(log n) complexity? You get the extra advantage of the vector data being contiguous.

Comment: @Yashas If the error codes aren't directly mapped to indices, i.e. 0-indexed and especially contiguous, how would you get the corresponding element? That's where one of the `map`s starts to look quite logical.

Comment: @underscore_d `std::unordered_map` or `std::vector` depending on the size of the dataset.

Comment: Just don't use C++11 "auto", it's a brain-damaged feature.