# How can I convert 0x70, 0x61, 0x73 ... etc to Pas ... etc in C++?

Tags: c++, hex, ascii, decimal

I am using MSVC++ 2010 Express, and I would love to know how to convert

```
BYTE Key[] = {0x50,0x61,0x73,0x73,0x77,0x6F,0x72,0x64};
```

to "Password" I am having a lot of trouble doing this.  :( I will use this knowledge to take things such as...

```
BYTE Key[] { 0xC2, 0xB3, 0x72, 0x3C, 0xC6, 0xAE, 0xD9, 0xB5, 0x34, 0x3C, 0x53, 0xEE, 0x2F, 0x43, 0x67, 0xCE };
```

And other various variables and convert them accordingly.

Id like to end up with "Password" stored in a char.

Comment: ummmm do you mean change hex to ascii?

Comment: What type do you want to end up with? `std::string`? `const char *`? What?

Comment: @BalaR that won't work as it's assuming the string is null terminated. Which it isn't, judging from the cost he posted.

Comment: @icktoofay I want to end up with a char

Comment: Is the fact that 0x70 is a lowercase p, but you've said you want "Password" with an uppercase P important?

Comment: @VaughnCato Sorry that was a typo.  :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you are lacking is a null terminator, so after doing this:

```
char Key_str[(sizeof Key)+1];
memcpy(Key_str,key,sizeof Key);
Key_str[sizeof Key] = '\0';
```

Key_str will be usable as a regular char * style string.

Answer (score 2):

Key is an array of bytes. If you want to store it in a `string`, for example, you should construct the string using its range constructor, that is:

```
string key_string(Key, Key + sizeof(Key)/sizeof(Key[0]));
```

Or if you can compile using C++11:

```
string key_string(begin(Key), end(Key));
```

To get a `char*` I'd go the C way and use `strndup`:

```
char* key_string = strndup(Key, sizeof(Key)/sizeof(Key[0]));
```

However, if you're using C++ I strongly suggest you use `string` instead of `char*` and only convert to `char const*` when absolutely necessary (e.g. when calling a C API). See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/801209/c-char-vs-stdstring) for good reasons to prefer `std::string`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I would like to store it into a char though.