# How to access an array inside a struct in c/c++

Tags: c++, arrays, string, struct, char

I have the below array,

```
struct Student{
char* Name;
int age;
Student* Next;
};
```

And i used to follow the below steps to access the char* fields.

Method 1;

```
Student s1 = {strdup("Name1"),26};
```

Method2:

```
Student s2;
s2.Name = strdup("Name2");
s2.age  = 26;
```

Here i wanted to know is there any other way to access the char* Field and if not is there a specific and best way to access  char* fields?.

Also what is the best way to have a datastructure like name, address and etc.. inside a struct. should i go with the above method char*? or can i have array instead? or string will make sense in this?(is there any other method is available instead of char*. char array[], string stringname )

My ultimate Aim is to have a data structure correctly with best access methodology. pls Help!!!

```
struct DataStruct{
(char*/char [] / string) Name; // Need a best way 
}
```

also the access mechanism.

if we have only three mechanisms like char* , char [] and string,
then please advise the best way of accessing them from int main().

Many Thanks

Comment: if you are dealing with C++, `std::string` the best!

Comment: Define "best". [[[[[[[[

Comment: if you are in c++, use classes, std::string and std::vector

Comment: Yes !, my code is on C++. thank you for the replay. may i have some more question on top of this

Comment: There is no language called C/C++ - pick one of the two

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf Hi i wanted to have a feasible datastructure , i am requesting : what is the best way to achieve that.

Comment: @UnholySheep Please consider in C++ way!. sorry for the confusion

Comment: hi @JeJo thanks for your reply, could you tell me why i should not use array or char*. any performance issues? pls descibe

Comment: @user2285375: I don't wanna repeat: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10937767/when-to-use-stdstring-vs-char?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/801209/char-vs-stdstring-in-c

Comment: C style string introduce an unnecessary "layer of pointer" (in terms of direct use). Also they have the inconvenience of being null terminated. `std::string` abstracts this away in an handy fashion.

Comment: Also, `char*` and `char[]` can be considered equivalent

Comment: thanks @Vivick , I would like to know with respect to accessing the char[] in my code. 
struct{
char name[25];
};
int main()
{
//accessing the name in the struct
}

pls help

Comment: Let's say you have an instance of said struct named `s`, do `char[25] name = s.Name;`

Comment: //Data Structure
struct NameStruct{
char Name[10];
};

int main()
{

        NameStruct NM1;
        NM1.Name = "Name";

        NameStruct NM2={"Name2"};
}

Could you tell me what's correct and wrong with the above example.
why i'm not able to access array element by 
NM1.Name = "Name";
what is wrong. 
And How i am able to access by initializing the object(thru constrctor - obj2 in the above example) @Vivick please comment

Comment: also what is it happening with respect to object initialisation.

Comment: Alright got it, I'll propose an answer

Comment: Thanks a lot @Vivick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As for what to choose between `char*`/`char[]` and `std::string`, as I said in a comment :

> C style strings introduce an unnecessary "layer of pointer" (in terms of direct use). Also they have the inconvenience of being null terminated. `std::string` abstracts this away in an handy fashion

Regarding the different initialization approaches :
Both are nearly equivalent **as is**.

This means that without any kind of transformation,

```
Student s1 = {strdup("Name1"),26};
```

and

```
Student s2;
s2.Name = strdup("Name2");
s2.age  = 26;
```

Are interchangeable.

The difference lies elsewhere :

```
Student s1 = {strdup("Name1"),26};
cout << s1.Name;

Student s2;
cout << s2.Name;
s2.Name = strdup("Name2");
s2.age  = 26;
```

Here, there is what we call [Undefined Behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). You are accessing `s2.Name` before it is initialized/given a value.

If you have to choose, prefer `Student s1 = {strdup("Name1"),26};` which guarantees that any use of the members is valid.
If you need (in some scenario) the second approach then be certain that what you are accessing is actually initialized.