# Why does my code keep returning before it is complete?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

Why does my code not run properly? As soon as it gets to the if else statement it takes one input from the user and then exits before I can enter anything else. I am not sure if it is due to the function not returning properly but I would really appreciate some help. Thanks.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

void studentenrollment (char answer);

int main()
{
    char answer;                                                                    //declaring variables for main
    cout << "Welcome to Luton Sixth Form" << endl;                                   //greeting the user
    cout << "Please State if you are enrolled or not at the sixth form: Y/N" << endl;//giving user options
    cin >> answer;//taking options from user
    studentenrollment(answer);                                                       //calling student enrollment function 

    return 0;
}

void studentenrollment (char answer)
{
    unsigned char name;
    int dob;
    if (answer=='Y'||answer=='y')
    {

        cout << "Welcome to higher education" << endl;
        cout << "Please state your name" << endl;
        cin >> name;
        ofstream myfile;
        myfile.open("StudentAccess.txt");
        myfile << name << endl;
        myfile.close();
        cout << "Your name is now saved, you have access to the gateway" << endl;
    }

    else if(answer=='N'||answer=='n')
    {
        cout << "Please state your name" << endl;
        cin >> name;
        cout << "Please enter your date of birth" << endl;
        cin >> dob;
        ofstream myfile;
        myfile.open("StudentEnrollment.txt");
        myfile << name << dob << endl;
        myfile.close();
        cout << "You will now go through enrollment" << endl;
    }

//    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I do not currently have a debugger set up as I am just in the early stages of C++

Comment: @JoshMarshall, what do you enter first? If you enter neither 'y' nor 'n' the program will exit.

Comment: If you are on Linux, just install gdb plus clang or gcc, compile with '-g' for having debug info in the binary, and start debugging... Takes less than 5 minutes to set up.

Comment: You are trying to store a name in a `char` variable. You might want a character array instead.

Comment: @JoshMarshall having a debugger should come before writing code. I can't play this up enough - you need a debugger & to know how to debug.

Comment: You tagged with "Visual Studio 2010". If you're actually using that, you have a debugger.

Comment: using Windows 8.1 OS..  I Enter 'Y' or 'N', if I enter 'N' the else if statement lets me enter the first input then closes

Comment: @JoshMarshall _" I do not currently have a debugger set up as I am just in the early stages of C++"_ You also have a debugger available if you're a beginner. That actually doesn't matter. It's your 1st tool at hand, nothing _"advanced"_!

Comment: @JoshMarshall also, if you are beginning c++, you don't need a full fledged debugger to debug code. In your case, simply checking the value stored in name after cin >> name would have been enough to catch your bug. This is most easily done by printing the variable "name" to the console using cout << name. Good luck with c++!

Comment: Thankyou guys, I am installing the windows developer kit now so I can set a debugger up as I can see that it is needed. I solved the problem though thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`unsigned char name;` looks incorrect. Choose `char name[MAX_LENGTH];` or `std::string name;`

**What happens**

```
cin >> name;  // Read just first character
cin >> dob;   // Try to read number, where rest of the name is left in the stream buffer
```

This certainly looks wrong unless the name is 1 letter wide.

Comment: Thankyou - that solved the issue I had been having, is using string better practice than using char[MAX_LENGTH]?

Comment: @JoshMarshall Yes it certainly is for [multiple reasons](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/801209/char-vs-stdstring-in-c).

Answer (score 1):

Problem can be this:

```
cin >> name;
```

you are entering name but storing it in `name` - which is just `unsigned char`. Use a larger array to store the name.

Answer (score 0):

If the variable **name** can contain more than 1 character you cannot declare it **unsigned char**, you can declare it **std::string**.  remember the

```
#include<string>
```