# Different ways to make a string?

Tags: c++, string

I'm new to c++ and I'd like to know right from the start,

Does any of these methods of making strings work exactly the same way and give the exact same results always in every case? is there any difference in the result in any of them?

```
1) char greeting [6] = { 'h','e','l','l','o','\0' };

2) char greeting[] = "hello";

3) #include <string>
   string greeting = "hello";
```

Comment: Does this post answer your question? http://stackoverflow.com/a/1287357/248756

Comment: Note that the first two are for C-style strings - only #3 creates a C++ string. See also [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/801209/char-vs-stdstring-in-c).

Comment: The first two are identical. You're missing a possibility though: `char *greeting = "hello";` and the similar `const char *greeting = "hello";`

Comment: @MarkRansom `char *greeting = "hello";` is deprecated since the dawn of C++. Better don't even mention it to beginners, it only hurts to know one can do that.

Comment: @BaummitAugen a complete answer would state that explicitly, just to make sure a newbie doesn't try it accidentally.

Comment: Maybe this could help too : http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/

Comment: "in every case" is a vague term. For example, if your case is "I realized the string was wrong and need to change it", the first two don't give the same result, because the first is far harder to change.

Comment: TL;DR: Use 3), read a book, search the thousands of existing questions and answers about C++ strings next time please.

Comment: Take a look at the [string] tag-wiki: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/string/info

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1) and 2) work exactly the same. Both create a 6-element non-heap-allocated array, and copy the characters `'h'`, `'e'`, `'l'`, `'l'`, `'o'`, `'\0'` to the array at runtime or load time.

3) creates an instance of `std::string` and calls its constructor which copies the characters `'h'`, `'e'`, `'l'`, `'l'`, `'o'`(, `'\0'`)*  to its internal memory buffer. (* The `'\0'` is not required to be stored in the memory buffer.)

There is another way to declare a string in C++, using a pointer to `char`:

```
const char* greeting = "hello";
```

This will not copy anything. It will just point the pointer to the first character `'h'` of the null-terminated `"hello"` string which is located somewhere in memory. The string is also read-only (modifying it causes undefined behavior), which is why one should use a pointer-to-`const` here.

If you're wondering which one to use, choose `std::string`, it's the safest and easiest.

Comment: 1 and 2 create objects on the stack **only if** they're local variables. If they're globals they go in static storage, and can be initialized at load time, i.e., without any runtime overhead.

Comment: Instead of using *stack* I would suggest *objects with automatic storage duration.*

Answer (score 1):

> Do these methods of making strings work exactly the same way and give the exact same results always in every case?

The first two are [array](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/arrays/) definitions:

```
char greeting [6] = { 'h','e','l','l','o','\0' };
char greeting [ ] = "hello";
```

*"work the same"* as in the second definition a `'\0'` is appended implicitly.

As for the third definition:

```
string greeting = "hello";
```

A [`string` is a class type object](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/) and as such it is more complex than a simple array.

> Is there any difference in the result in any of them?

There is a quantitative<sup>1</sup> and qualitative<sup>2</sup> difference between the first two and the third stemming from the fact that `std::string` is a class type object.

---

<sup>1. Quantitative: arrays occupy less memory space than string.</sup>

<sup>2. Qualitative: string provides resource management and many facilities for element manipulation.</sup>