# Difference between std::string and const char*?

Tags: c++, c++11

What's the difference between std::string and const char*?
consider following example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
int main()
{
    const char* myName1{ "Alex" }; 
    std::cout << myName1 << '\n';
    std::string myName2{ "Alex" }; 
    std::cout << myName2 << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

are they the same?

Comment: You are aware that there is no `std::string` in this example code?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [char\* vs std::string in c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/801209/char-vs-stdstring-in-c)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`std::string` will give you the ability to use its member functions and most importantly to modify its contents. The initial data will likely<sup>1</sup> be copied to a dynamically allocated memory location when the program reaches its constructor. It will also store its size.

`const char*` is only a pointer value that points to a constant that is gonna be baked into the binary. There's no size information stored, and all functions operating on it have to rely on the presence of the `'\0'` value at the end.

---

<sup>1</sup> It's possible that Small-String Optimization kicks in here.

Answer (score 0):

As soon as you want to *store* some string, `const char *` doesn't do, you'll need `char *`. And you'll have to allocate memory for that `char *` to point at. And you'll have to figure out *how much* memory to allocate. And then reallocate more if you want to, say, append to that string. And you'll have to remember *freeing* that memory before your pointer goes out of scope (like, an exception being thrown somewhere).

Well, `std::string` relieves you of all of that. That's the big difference.

Just like C arrays and `std::vector`...

---

But within the scope of your example, there is very little actual difference.