# Transform uppercase letters to lowercase and vice-versa using single parameter function (C++)

Tags: c++, string, cpu-word, uppercase, lowercase

I have the `trans` function which uses a single parameter, has to be void, and returns through `c` the opposite case of a letter from a word input in `main`.

```
Example:
input: dOgdoG
output: DoGDOg
```

The function does change the case, but i cant figure out a way to build the new word / replace the old one because i keep getting compiling errors regarding "const char" or "invalid conversions".

*The following program gives error "invalid conversion from `char` to `const char*`*

I only changed the type of the function for example purposes.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

char trans(char c)
{
    if(c >= 'a' && c <= 'z')
        return c-32;
    else
        if(c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z')
            return c+32;
}

int main()
{
    char s[101], s2[101] = "";
    cin >> s;
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<strlen(s); i++)
    {
        strncat(s2, trans(s[i]), 1);
    }
    cout<<s2;
    return 0;
}
```

EDIT:
I changed from the `char` function to a `void` function and removed the body of the `for`.

```
void trans(char c)
{
    if(c >= 'a' && c <= 'z')
        c-=32;
    else
        if(c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z')
            c+=32;
}

int main()
{
    char s[101], s2[101] = "";
    cin >> s;
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<strlen(s); i++)
    {
        /// i dont know what to put here
    }
    cout<<s2;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Look up the `toupper` and `tolower` functions.

Comment: Don't mess around with `strncat`; you **know** that `s2` is large enough to hold the result, because you wrote it that way. So just do it: `s2[i] = trans(s[i]);`. And don't forget the nul terminator; that comes after the last character, so looping up to `strlen(s)` won't reach it.

Comment: @PeteBecker: Or just make the changes to `s` directly.

Comment: @ScottHunter -- maybe, but the question asks about "build the new word / replace the old one", and the code in the quesiton builds the new word.

Comment: Having `i<strlen(s)` in the `for` loop probably means that your loop has `O(N*N)` time complexity, where `N` is the length of `s`, since `strlen(s)` itself has `O(N)` complexity, and the `for` loop itself runs `N` times. I'd recommend having the statement `int len = strlen(s);` before the loop, and then have `i<len` instead of `i<strlen(s)`. (Take a look at https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2001/12/11/back-to-basics/.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't reinvent the wheel. The standard library has functions to identify uppercase and lowercase letter, and to change case. Use them.

```
char trans(char ch) {
    unsigned char uch = ch; // unfortunately, character classification function require unsigned char
    if (std::isupper(uch))
        return std::tolower(uch);
    else
        return std::toupper(uch);
}
```

You might be inclined to change that `else` branch to `else if (std::islower(uch) return std::toupper(uch); else return uch;`, but that's not necessary; `std::toupper` only changes lowercase letters to uppercase, so it won't affect characters that aren't lowercase.

Then, when you call it, just copy the result:

```
int i = 0;
for ( ; i < strlen(s); ++i)
    s2[i] = tran(s[i]);
s2[i] = '\0';
```

EDIT:

Since there seems to be a requirement to do things the hard way, let's change `trans` to match:

```
void trans(char& ch) {
    unsigned char uch = ch; // unfortunately, character classification function require unsigned char
    if (std::isupper(uch))
        ch = std::tolower(uch);
    else
        ch = std::toupper(uch);
}
```

And now, you can just apply it in place:

```
for (int i = 0; i < strlen(s); ++i)
    trans(s[i]);
```

I called this "the hard way" because with the original version of `trans` you can use it directly to modify the original string:

```
for (int i = 0; i < strlen(s); ++i)
    s[i] = trans(s[i]);
```

and you can use it to copy the string:

```
for (int i = 0; i < strlen(s); ++i)
    s2[i] = trans(s[i]);
// don't forget the terminating nul
```

With pass by reference, you can **only** modify in place; copying requires an additional step:

```
strcpy(s2, s1);
for (int i = 0; i < strlen(s); ++i)
    trans(s2[i]);
```

Comment: not trying to reinvent anything, i know those functions, but i need to do it the way i did, plus, i did mention the char function was for example purposes only, as i need to use a void function which is what i dont understand how to do
I will edit the question to make it more obvious

Answer (score 1):

`strncat` takes 2 *strings* and a number as parameters; your second argument is a `char`, not a string.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`std::transform`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform) with string utility functions like [`std::isupper`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isupper), [`std::toupper`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/toupper) and similarly for lowercase. Since, the question is tagged [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) `std::string` is preferred over `const char*`<sup>1</sup> for strings.

```
#include <string>
#include <cctype>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

char trans(unsigned char c){

   if (std::isupper(c)) 
      return std::tolower(c);
   else if (std::islower(c)) 
      return std::toupper(c);
   else
      return c;
}

int main(){
  std::string s = "dOgdoG12";
  std::string out;
  out.resize(s.length());
  
  std::transform(s.begin(), s.end(), out.begin(), trans);
  std::cout << out; // DoGDOg12
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/78jzKbvn1)

---

<sub>1. SO post on [`char*` vs `std::string`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/801209)</sub>