# c++ std::vector performance [reference required]

Tags: c++, stl, vector

I'm writing a parallel implementation of some data structures. I'd like to find out if someone know about difference in performance between pure pointers and std::vector. If you know trustful docs about it, please write URL/book name/whatever. Any hints are welcome!

Comment: What is the commonality between pointers and `std::vector`?

Comment: Unfortunately I know nothing about this, but +1 for a very good, probably very common question :-)

Comment: Both can store any kind of data. I ask cause I don't know which one is faster.

Comment: I assume that by "pure pointers" you mean hand-crafted dynamically allocated arrays?

Comment: @Adam: no, they can't hold "any kind of data". The can hold `n>=0` objects of the *same* type. What do you mean exactly?

Comment: Then see Klaim's answer. Use `std::vector<>`.

Comment: @Andre: I meant that can store an instance of any class/primitive, either pointer to function and so on... My question is which one is faster, cause I don't know how std::vector have been written in standard lib.

Comment: @Adam: you can almost certainly look at the source code for vector for any particular implementation you're interested in. In my installation of GCC, it's in `/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/4.3.4/include/c++/bits/stl_vector.h`, but for closed-source compilers it's still (normally) in headers somewhere. If you want an answer that's applicable to *any* C++ implementation then you're out of luck because the standard doesn't guarantee precise performance, only algorithmic complexity. If you want an answer that's applicable to any *sensible* implementation then DeadMG is about right.

Answer (score 5):

The difference is **usage** and **implementation** relative.

Comment: +1: `std::vector<>` is just a *friendly* dynamically allocated array.

Comment: I "hid" the developpement of this answer in "history", but the initial sentence should be enough for most of us.

Answer (score 3):

You can make std::vector as fast as normal pointers by using the unchecked operator[] and resizing appropriately. The reality is that vector is a compile-time abstraction over a pointer- not a runtime one, unless you choose to use extras. What's much more important is the vastly increased safety vector offers- debugging iterators, automatic and safe resource management, etc. There is no reason to use a raw pointer.

Edit: My reference is that profiling run you did before you even considered losing the safety of vector.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this answer in a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2740020/c-stl-array-vs-vector-raw-element-accessing-performance/2740178#2740178), accessing an element in a dynamically-allocated array versus a `std::vector` will be roughly the same. There's some good analysis in that question and in [this one as well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1071674/dynamically-allocated-arrays-or-stdvector).

Answer (score 0):

If you mean to compare a `std::vector` with some hand-written dynamic array here are some points of reference:

- The resizing factor on insertion is important. This factor isn't specified by the standard but is usually between 1.5 or 2 and it must guarantee amortized constant time on insertion operations.
- The allocator: A lot of the performance depends on the allocation mechanism that is used, same goes for your pointers.
- Boundary checking can occur in `std::vector` if you call `vector::at` which cannot happen with raw pointers.

Comment: the resizing factor isn't relevant if you're making an apples to apples comparison. A raw array has to be sized up front, so presumably you'd do the same with `vector`.

Comment: @jalf: it's not really clear what "pure pointers" means, so it's more of an apples to some-unspecified-fruit-in-a-locked-box comparison.

Comment: @jalf: I thought if he compared something with `vector` dynamic resizing is a must. If he doesn't need dynamic resizing he should use `std::array` anyway.