# Good .NET library for fast streaming / batching trigonometry (Atan)?

Tags: .net, performance, streaming, trigonometry

I need to call Atan on millions of values per second.  Is there a good library to perform this operation in batch very fast.  For example, a library that streams the low level logic using something like SSE?

I have profiled the application, and I know that this call to Atan is a bottleneck.

I know that there is support for this in OpenCL, but I would prefer to do this operation on the CPU.  The target machine might not support OpenCL.

I also looked into using OpenCV, but it's accuracy for Atan angles is only ~0.3 degrees.  I need accurate results.

Comment: What accuracy do you need and what are your input values (int, float, double, other ? single value, or y / x pair ?)

Comment: Single or double precision is OK.  I would like accuracy of about 1/3600 of a degree.

Comment: I did some beter performance tracing with dotTrace, and found that the bottleneck actually wasn't the Atan call, but the assignment operation that I was using on the same line.  I'm still interested, however, in any good trig libraries for streaming / batched operations.

Comment: Let me guess. Is your assignment statement indexing a vector in debug code, as in this example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1932222/c-vector-vs-array-time/1933356#1933356

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you try [Brahma](http://brahma.ananthonline.net/)? To my understanding, it's a free and open source GPGPU library that doesn't depend on OpenCL, instead converting code to HLSL/GLSL shaders via LINQ.

EDIT: Sample code:

```
ComputationProvider provider = new ComputationProvider();
CompiledQuery query = provider.Compile<DataParallelArray<float>>(
    data => from value in data
            select (float)Math.Atan(value)); // Do your calculations here...

DataParallelArray<float> input = new DataParallelArray<float>(provider, new float[] { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, }); // etc...
IQueryable result = provider.Run(query, input);

foreach (float value in result)
    Console.WriteLine(value);
```

Comment: Very interesting.  I hadn't heard of Brahma.

Comment: It doesn't look like it provides trig functions?

Comment: Edited answer. Brahma does in fact support trig functions. All System.Math functions are supported as long as their is an equivalent in HLSL/GLSL.