# How to write efficient Genetic Algorithms in C++

Tags: c++, algorithm, visual-studio-2010, vector, genetic-algorithm

I am trying to write a C++ program for the [canonical genetic algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genetic_programming), where you have a population of individuals (chromosomes) of length N, where each element is a O or 1.

I have started writing my program using **STL vectors**, but before I go more deeply into it I would like to ask your opinions about how to write the functions and the data structures in the most efficient way.

Memory footprint is not a problem, I have a population about 100 individuals where each of them are a 64 character long string of 0-s and 1-s. The performance on the other hand is very important, as there would be about **thousands of generations, each having thousands of operations.**

Here is my implementation so far (just the most important funcitions and the data structure):

```
typedef vector<int> chromosome;
typedef vector<chromosome> population;

population popul;
float eval[number];

void cross_chromosomes( const chromosome &parent_a, const chromosome &parent_b, chromosome &child_a, chromosome &child_b )
{
    int crossing_point = crossing_point_gen( gen );

    child_a.reserve( length );
    child_a.insert( child_a.end(), parent_a.cbegin(), parent_a.cbegin() + crossing_point );
    child_a.insert( child_a.end(), parent_b.cbegin() + crossing_point, parent_b.cend() );

    child_b.reserve( length );
    child_b.insert( child_b.end(), parent_b.cbegin(), parent_b.cbegin() + crossing_point );
    child_b.insert( child_b.end(), parent_a.cbegin() + crossing_point, parent_a.cend() );
}

void calculate_eval()
{
    for( int i = 0; i < number; i++ )
    {
        eval[i] = evaluate_chromosome( popul[i] );
    }
}
```

**Do you think it is an efficient way of implementing this algorithm?** I originally used vector for the chromosome, but I have read this question: [C++ Vector vs Array (Time)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1932222/c-vector-vs-array-time) and I updated my code to `vector<int>`.

Do you think there are other optimisations I should do with my code to make it more efficient? Is the crossing code efficient as it is now?

Comment: I'm not sure that's the right way to go about this problem. It would be better if you ran the program, found that it is indeed too slow (by your own definition of what "fast" is). Otherwise, why worry about speed at all ?

Comment: I agree with @chetan. Rule 8 from [C++ Coding Standards](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/c++cs.htm) by Sutter and Alexandrescu: "Don't optimize prematurely."

Comment: I have always been critical of genetic algorithms, or perhaps I just don't have an appreciation.  If you know what is fit, then just construct an organism made up of that and be done with it. :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The crossover code seems at max efficiency for what you are trying to do with the vectors. From my experience with genetic algorithms, the fitness function and selection operator are the most time intensive. Since you will be using crossover and mutation on a sample of the population you don't have to worry too much about the efficiency of the crossover operator. Focus on defining a good representation for your data and an optimal fitness function implementation.

Comment: Most interesting possible solutions to a widely studied requirement. Look up in google 'efficient generic algorithms in C++'

Answer (score 4):

What about taking advantage of the embarasing parallelism in evolutionary algorithm. And what about trying to port your solution on GPUs. And like chetan and David said it might be much less time consuming to use an existing framework than write your own *fast* one.

[OpenBeagle](http://beagle.sf.net) and [EO](http://eodev.sourceforge.net/) are well known well supported and very efficient frameworks.

Note that the only part that really needs to be fast in an evolutionary algorithm is the evaluation everything else is usually not time consuming. You can also look for [DEAP](http://deap.googlecode.com) that allows to distribute very easily the evaluation (and more) on supercomputer (we tested on 1024 cores of the Colosse super computer by changing a single line of code in our serial algorithm).

Comment: You are turning an easy exercise problem into something more involved, but you're essentially right: if your need is performance, then use the right tool.

Comment: Considering parallelism, [openGA](https://github.com/Arash-codedev/openGA) is another C++ library which is flexible, with low overhead and it can adjust the number of CPU cores involved.

Answer (score 0):

If you already know what the size of your arrays are going to be, then using arrays will be much faster than using vectors. Vectors require a lot more overhead than arrays.

Comment: This is not correct. If you know the size of your arrays beforehand, you can vector::reserve that space or pass the size to the vector constructor. Assuming you configure Visual Studio's checked iterators correctly for your Release build there should not be any performance penalty for using a vector over an array.

Comment: Ah, I did not know about reserving space with vectors. Thank you for clearing that up. Just out of curiosity, what compiler settings need to be set if I am not using Visual Studio?

Comment: I have no idea. I don't think there is any analogue to Microsoft's debug iterators and secure scl in g++, but I have close to no experience with compilers other than Microsoft's.  I believe the performance killing (but helpful for debugging) checked iterators only appear in versions of VS >= 2005. I mentioned this Visual Studio issue as the question is tagged with it; it's not specifically related to using vector::reserve to improve allocation efficiency.

Comment: In this article (1st Google result outside of MSDN), it says that for VS2010 it is not enabled by default for release builds. http://preshing.com/20110807/the-cost-of-_secure_scl

Comment: So if I understand correctly, there would be a performance penalty for using vectors in any development environment, unless you are in VisualStudio and explicitly set VisualStudio's checked iterators?

Comment: I think it means just the opposite. You can pretty much use vectors instead of arrays without noticing any difference, as long as you use .reserve()

Answer (score 0):

You could compact your memory somewhat: using 4 bytes to represent a binary value is quite wasteful. I would suggest replacing the `chromosome` with either `std::array<unsigned char, 64>` or `std::bitset<64>` to pack it more.

Even though you claim not to be worried about memory, compacting memory leads to better cache usage in the CPU which may speed up the program.

If you really want to optimize the heck out of your program, however, the only sane way to go at it is to use a full-blown profiler. I've used callgrind quite successively in the past, but there are others out there, depending on your development environment.

Comment: There is a trade off here: packing memory may incur some access penalty if you are to extract information from each bit. There are also alignment considerations (which may be handled by your `std::bitset` implementation however). The best thing to do is to try both and profile, but not guess (but I believe you know all that).