# How to change mode from c++98 mode in Dev-C++ to a mode that supports C++0x (range based for)?

Tags: c++, c++11, compiler-construction, dev-c++

I am just learning how to write range based for loops, but the only problem is that my compiler, Orwell Dev-C++ doesn't seem to support it in its default mode (which is c++98). How can I change this mode to another one that supports this feature (and other features of C++0x). Thanks. Also:

This was the error message: [Error] range-based-for loops are not allowed in C++98 mode

I run Windows 8

The version I have of Dev C++ is 5.3.0.3

And the compiler is TDM-GCC 4.6.1 64 bit.

Thanks to everyone

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Go to **Tools -> Compiler Options -> "Compiler" tab**

Check the checkbox labeled, "*Add the following commands when calling the compiler*"
And add in the text entry box, "**-std=c++11**" or if that doesn't work "**-std=C++0x**"

Should be something like that anyway, I haven't had Dev C++ installed for many years, so I had to look at some screenshots on Google to remember.

Comment: hmmm....doesn't seem to work. the error messave is: [Error] unrecognized option '-static-libgcc-std=c++0x'

Comment: oh...I was doing it wrong. It actually does work. Thanks so much.

Comment: @user2457666 If this answer worked for you, you should mark it as accepted (use the check mark to the left, just below the number of votes received).

Comment: Thanks @Jamin Grey, it worked for me.

Here is the screenshot of how it should look like in the compiler option. https://i.postimg.cc/SR12Zm6P/Capture.png

Answer (score 11):

1. Download from the following link
   http://orwelldevcpp.blogspot.in/2015/04/dev-c-511-released.html
2. Go to Tools->Compiler Option->Programs

and add `-std=c++11`

see the  image

[image]

Answer (score 7):

In Dev C++ 5.2.0.3 it's as simple as go to Tools->Compiler Options->Settings->Code Generation
and setting *Language standard (-std)* to *ISO C++11*

Answer (score 6):

By default, support for the most recent version of C++ is not enabled. It shall be explicitly enabled by going to:[image]

Here, select the "Settings" tab, and within it, the "Code Generation" tab. There, in "Language standard (-std)" select "ISO C++ 11":

[image]

Ok that. You are now ready to compile C++11!

Answer (score 0):

Was facing the same issue in Code::Blocks. to fix the problem, in Build Options->Compiler Flags, tick the box "Have g++ follow the c++11 ISO C++ language standard [-std=c++11]"

Answer (score 0):

In Dev-C++ 5.11 an error comes in new tab like this:

> This file requires compiler and library support for the ISO C++ 2011 standard. This support is currently experimental, and must be enabled with the `-std=c++11` or `-std=gnu++11` compiler options.

For this you have to follow four simple steps:

1. Go to Tools Tab
2. Select Compiler Options..
3. Go to General tab
4. Check the checkbox named "Add following commands when calling the compiler", write this statement `-std=c++11`, and then press OK

Conclusion: Error is removed

Answer (score 0):

Tested On: Dev-C++ 5.11

---

if you want to code with c instead of c++ and have this issue, do these steps:

1. Tools > Compiler Options > Settings Tab > Code Generations
2. set the **"Language standard (-std)"** to **"ISO C99"**

you still get the warning although it works for you now.