# Dev-C++ "to_string is not a member of std" error

Tags: c++, string

I have a problem with converting `int` to `string` in Dev-C++.

I have the proper `#include`, but still I get:

> [Error] 'to_string' is not a member of 'std'

```
const int MAX_KOSZT = 999999;    
string convert(int val) {
  if (val == MAX_KOSZT) 
  {
    return "--";
  } 
  else {
    if (val < 10) {
      return "0" + std::to_string(val);
    } 
    else {
      return std::to_string(val);
    }
  }
}

void getCout()
{
  cout << convert(sciana) << "," << convert(chodnik);
}
```

Comment: Did you `#include <string>`? C++11 standard is on?

Comment: I write that i got proper include.

Comment: `Dev-C++`  That is not a compiler.  That is an IDE.  What is the actual compiler used to compile your code?  Probably some (old) version of gcc.

Comment: You should present a [MCVE] in your question though. Who knows what your understanding of _proper include_ is?

Comment: I've got completely different [compiler errors](http://ideone.com/7FHnoI)

Comment: PaulMcKenzie i use this -> TDM-GCC 4.9.2 64-bit Release

Comment: @Bulit compile it with g++ compiler

Comment: πάντα ῥε sory I assumed that word proper is clear

Comment: @Bulit But why even have all of this code you've posted to test whether `std::to_string` works?  Look at this:  http://ideone.com/xndpeR  See how simple that is.  That's all you need to demonstrate to us to show us the issue.  No missing headers, a complete, but minimal example, etc..  Now, does that example at the link compile for you?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [How to change mode from c++98 mode in Dev-C++ to a mode that supports C++0x (range based for)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16951376/how-to-change-mode-from-c98-mode-in-dev-c-to-a-mode-that-supports-c0x-ran)

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie i paste more code thx to what everyone can understand more is better than less

NathanOliver Yes this can be possible duplicate but i didnt even know that there is mode change in Dev-C++

Comment: @Built -- More is not better if the issue is with a simple function.  Any compiler error can be duplicated with a tiny amount of code, not entire functions with missing variables and headers.  The code I linked to is the kind of example you should have started with on your own.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie k i will remember that thx anyway

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The compiler defaults to not having C++11 features available.

I suspect you need to change the language standard to ISOC++11 or GNUC++11 in the compiler settings.

If you are using a project, you will find this in the project options (right click on the project). If not, you will find this, I think, in the "tools" menu.

The option you need looks something like this http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/introduction/devcpp/devcpp2.png

Comment: This work great i didnt even know that this exist in Dev-C++ big thx man

Comment: Same thing as @Bulit, I didn't know about this. Really helping :)