# How do I combine an int with a string in a varC++

Tags: c++, string

I have this (example) code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
int main()
  {
    string myvar = "string" + 5;
    cout<<myvar<<endl;
    return 0;
  }
```

I want this to print `string5`, like it would in `Python`, but instead, it prints `g`. How do I get `C++` to do this? I haven't gotten anywhere with googling.

I'm pretty new to C++

Comment: You may want to refresh your memory: this doesn't work in Python either!

Comment: Nor would it in Perl, but it would work in JavaScript.

Comment: If you're new to C++, a good thing to learn now would be to never use `endl`. If you want to portably print a newline, use `<< '\n'`; if you want to flush a stream, use `std::flush`.

Comment: But you often want both, so you might as well use endl.

Comment: @MarkVY If you want both, the best solution is `... << '\n' << std::flush`. But really you shouldn't need to flush all that often.

Comment: @MarkVY this would work in python, but not implicitly. You'd need to also convert `5` into a string through the `str()` function, or just surround it with quotes. All my point was was that you can simply add items to each other in python for them to combine.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
string myvar = "string" + std::to_string(5);
cout<<myvar<<endl; // prints string5
```

Comment: When I run this I get "'to_string is not a member of 'std'". When I remove `std::` I get "'to_string' was not declared in this scope". Am I on an outdated client? I'm using Dev-C++.

Comment: please refer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35874215/dev-c-to-string-is-not-a-member-of-std-error?lq=1

Comment: Need to change the language standard to ISOC++11 or GNUC++11 in the compiler settings.