# Allocate multiple structs in memory

Tags: c++, dll, struct, cen-xfs

i need pass multiple values to memory, i need make various country to CEN/XFS.

This api: [CashDispenser - CDM](ftp://ftp.cenorm.be/CWA/CEN/WS-XFS/cwa14050/cwa14050-05-2000-Nov.pdf)

Struct reference: WFSCDMCURRENCYEXP

How am i trying to do:

```
HRESULT WINAPI WFPGetInfo(HSERVICE hService, DWORD dwCategory, LPVOID lpQueryDetails, DWORD dwTimeOut, HWND hWnd, REQUESTID ReqID) {
WFSRESULT * lpWFSResult;
WFSCDMSTATUS CdmStatus;
WFSCDMCAPS CdmCapabilities; 
WFSCDMCASHUNIT CdmCash;
WFSCDMCURRENCYEXP CdmCurrency;
HRESULT result;

result = WFMAllocateBuffer(sizeof(WFSRESULT), WFS_MEM_ZEROINIT | WFS_MEM_SHARE, (void**)&lpWFSResult); 

    if(result != WFS_SUCCESS){
        return WFS_ERR_INTERNAL_ERROR;
    }

if(dwCategory == WFS_INF_CDM_CURRENCY_EXP){

    const int countCurrencies = 2;

    WFSCDMCURRENCYEXP** ppCdmCurrencies;

    result = WFMAllocateMore(sizeof(WFSCDMCURRENCYEXP*) * (countCurrencies+1), lpWFSResult, (void**)&ppCdmCurrencies);

    lpWFSResult->hService=hService;      
    lpWFSResult->RequestID=ReqID;
    lpWFSResult->u.dwEventID=WFS_INF_CDM_CURRENCY_EXP;
    lpWFSResult->hResult=WFS_SUCCESS;

    result = WFMAllocateMore(sizeof(WFSCDMCURRENCYEXP), lpWFSResult, (void**)&ppCdmCurrencies[0]);

    WFSCDMCURRENCYEXP& cmdCurrency0(*ppCdmCurrencies[0]);
    memcpy(cmdCurrency0.cCurrencyID, "AED", 3);
    cmdCurrency0.sExponent = 0;

    WFSCDMCURRENCYEXP& cmdCurrency1(*ppCdmCurrencies[1]);
    memcpy(cmdCurrency1.cCurrencyID, "AFA", 3);
    cmdCurrency1.sExponent = 0;

    lpWFSResult->lpBuffer = ppCdmCurrencies;
    logFile.close();
}
}
```

Comment: `CdmCurrency.cCurrencyID[3] = 'ARG';` does not do what you think it does.

Comment: What? No received the value?

Comment: Use `'` for a single char or `"` for a sequence of chars (usually)

Comment: @MatheusCardozo You rather need something like `strcpy(CdmCurrency.cCurrencyID,"ARG");`.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ : `strcpy` will copy *four* characters (including the trailing null), but `.cCurrencyID` is only three characters long.

Comment: Actually, if I were the OP, I'd make .cCurrencyID be four characters long - and leave space for a trailing null - it won't even make the structure any bigger.

Comment: @MartinBonner I know, I just wanted to point out that simple assignment won't do there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you try to handle WFS_INF_CDM_CURRENCY_EXP message to get information about currencies in your CDM.

Read XFS specification carefully:

> Output Param LPWFSCDMCURRENCYEXP *lppCurrencyExp; Pointer to a NULL-terminated array of pointers to WFSCDMCURRENCYEXP structures

This means that you must allocate an array of pointers to WFSCDMCURRENCYEXP with size N+1 and set last item to null.

In CEN/XFS you cannot  use standard new or malloc for memory allocation.
You need to use WFMAllocateBuffer and WFMAllocateMore to allocate memory for XFS structures that you return to caller.

For you task yo need something like this:

```
HRESULT WINAPI WFPGetInfo(HSERVICE hService, DWORD dwCategory, LPVOID lpQueryDetails, DWORD dwTimeOut, HWND hWnd, REQUESTID ReqID) {

WFSRESULT * lpWFSResult;
WFSCDMSTATUS CdmStatus;
WFSCDMCAPS CdmCapabilities; 
WFSCDMCASHUNIT CdmCash;
WFSCDMCURRENCYEXP CdmCurrency;
HRESULT result;

result = WFMAllocateBuffer(sizeof(WFSRESULT), WFS_MEM_ZEROINIT | WFS_MEM_SHARE, (void**)&lpWFSResult); 

    if(result != WFS_SUCCESS){
        return WFS_ERR_INTERNAL_ERROR;
    }

if(dwCategory == WFS_INF_CDM_CURRENCY_EXP){

    const int countCurrencies = 2;

    WFSCDMCURRENCYEXP** ppCdmCurrencies;
    result = WFMAllocateBuffer(sizeof(WFSCDMCURRENCYEXP*) * (countCurrencies+1), WFS_MEM_ZEROINIT | WFS_MEM_SHARE, (void**)&ppCdmCurrencies);

    lpWFSResult->hService=hService;      
    lpWFSResult->RequestID=ReqID;
    lpWFSResult->u.dwEventID=WFS_INF_CDM_CURRENCY_EXP;
    lpWFSResult->hResult=WFS_SUCCESS;

    result = WFMAllocateMore(sizeof(WFSCDMCURRENCYEXP), lpWFSResult, (void**)&ppCdmCurrencies[0]);

    WFSCDMCURRENCYEXP& cmdCurrency0(*ppCdmCurrencies[0]);
    memcpy(cmdCurrency0.cCurrencyID, "AED", 3);
    cmdCurrency0.sExponent = 0;

    result = WFMAllocateMore(sizeof(WFSCDMCURRENCYEXP), lpWFSResult, (void**)&ppCdmCurrencies[1]);

    WFSCDMCURRENCYEXP& cmdCurrency1(*ppCdmCurrencies[1]);
    memcpy(cmdCurrency1.cCurrencyID, "AFA", 3);
    cmdCurrency1.sExponent = 0;

    lpWFSResult->lpBuffer = ppCdmCurrencies;
    logFile.close();
    return WFS_SUCCESS;
}
}
```

That's not so simple to manipulate with XFS. It's too many complex API structures with different rules of allocation and data representation. Please read carefully XFS manuals. In the first book ftp://ftp.cen.eu/CWA/CEN/WS-XFS/CWA16926/CWA%2016926-1.pdf many conceptual things is described. About configuration, memory mangement and so on.

Comment: Man, In the end, it was not necessary: memcpy(lpWFSResult->lpBuffer,&CdmCurrency,sizeof(WFSCDMCURRENCYEXP)); ????

Comment: Yes, that's not necessary. You already allocate memory for all structures and store only address of it in lpWFSResult->lpBuffer

Comment: Hey guy, this error -15 appears, WFS_ERR_INTERNAL_ERROR..ow god.

Comment: Make log here, and Discovered (
Error in the 2 AllocateMore)...See [Image Compile](http://imgur.com/raB2ZXe)

Comment: Try fixed code. I made mistake in second WFMAllocateMore, need to use lpWFSResult as base address.

Comment: You use lpResultBuffer in first WFMAllocateMore,but don't it is declared in scope. ????

Comment: I wrote that code in by memory, and don't check any spelling. I only want to show the basic idea of XFS memory manipulation. Check fixed version

Comment: haha ok, thank you man, i 'am Brazilian, sorry for my bad english, you helped me,but no working.. :( Continued with -15 error.

Comment: When you get error -15? Can you show me the complete code?

Comment: Hey Alex, you can help me ?

Comment: HI, I've looked to my old project and found some differences. I'll send it to you later

Comment: See fixed example in my reply. I can't check it in real XFS environment, but this method was used in real project. If you continue receive errors, please write me location where you get it. I'll try to help you.
P.S. I'm going to be away till next Monday

Answer (score 3):

Your code looks very C-ish.

An idiomatic way to do this in c++ would be:

```
struct WFSCDMCURRENCYEXP
{
   std::string     cCurrencyID;
   SHORT           sExponent;
};

std::vector<WFSCDMCURRENCYEXP> CdmCurrencies {
    { "ARG", 3 } ,
    { "EUA", 3 } ,
    // lots more countries
};
```

---

**Update:**

I just noticed you apparently interact with a c-style API, and using that `struct` might be required in its original form.
Though in c++ you still can use a `std::vector` to manage a dynamically allocated, contiguous array of that struct:

```
typedef struct _wfs_cdm_currency_exp
{
   CHAR            cCurrencyID[3];
   SHORT           sExponent;
} WFSCDMCURRENCYEXP, * LPWFSCDMCURRENCYEXP;

std::vector<WFSCDMCURRENCYEXP> CdmCurrencies {
    { { 'A', 'R', 'G' }, 3 } , // Note that the cCurrencyID is a non null terminated 
                               // array here
    { { 'E', 'U', 'A' }, 3 } ,
    // lots more countries
};

LPWFSCDMCURRENCYEXP pCdmCurrencies = &CdmCurrencies[0];
```

Comment: Man, have a compile error this block: std::vector<WFSCDMCURRENCYEXP> CdmCurrencies {.....
}; <---

Comment: @MatheusCardozo What error specifically? I've updated my answer a bit. Here's a [compiling demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5729efe78afc70da)). Ensure c++11 is enabled with your compiler.

Comment: @MatheusCardozo So you read that warning also? Get a recent compiler or enable c++11 explicitly.

Comment: @MatheusCardozo Which IDE are you using? You should add one of the options mentioned in the warning to your projects c++ compiler flags.

Comment: @MatheusCardozo Note you should ensure to install the latest MinGW GCC version also. IIRC Dev-C++ comes packaged with an old outdated GCC version.

Comment: Hey, How's that part? memcpy(lpWFSResult->lpBuffer,&CdmCurrency,sizeof(WFSCDMCURRENCYEXP));

Comment: @MatheusCardozo _"Hey, How's that part?"_ What do you need that for?

Comment: @MatheusCardozo Regarding compiler flags [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16951376/how-to-change-mode-from-c98-mode-in-dev-c-to-a-mode-that-supports-c0x-ran) also please. (And no please don't start a chat, just ignore the message).

Comment: @MatheusCardozo You probably should be able to write: `lpWFSResult->lpBuffer = pCdmCurrencies;`

Answer (score 1):

Declare an array:

```
WFSCDMCURRENCYEXP CdmCurrency[2];
memcpy( CdmCurrency[0].cCurrencyID, "ARG", 3);
CdmCurrency[0].sExponent = 0; 
memcpy( CdmCurrency[1].cCurrencyID, "EUA", 3);
CdmCurrency[1].sExponent = 0;

memcpy(lpWFSResult->lpBuffer, CdmCurrency, 2*sizeof(WFSCDMCURRENCYEXP));
//                                         ^^
```

Don't forget you will need to copy more memory.

Also note I have fixed the setting of `.cCurrencyID` - a character literal (with single quotes) can only contain a single character.  To move multiple characters, you will need to call memcpy from a string.  Normally I would suggest using `std::string` rather than `char [3]`, but you can't use memcpy if you do, and it probably wouldn't be a good idea to pass a `std::string` across a DLL boundary.

Comment: Did you remember to multiply the sizeof by the count?  Does lpWFSResult->lpBuffer point at a large enough buffer?  How does it "not work"?

Comment: Yes, this buffer have size. But in my log not rolling nothing, the xfs ignore this.

Answer (score 0):

You can call malloc to allocate multiple structs, if they are what is called POD - plain old data - or structures with no destructors, member functions, or member classes with these characteristics.

The only reason for doing that is to be compatible with C, however, or for writing very low level code.

As a general rule, you want to create an std::vector. The vector handles all the memory for you, and you can push_back as many members as you require. Use reserve (or resize) if efficiency is important. There's also a member called data() which is there for C compatibility (however C can't call your vector, at least not easily).

Answer (score 0):

your code keeps throwing WFS_ERR_INTERNAL_ERROR because you havent got a fully functional XFS environment setup, setup a proper configuration, or emulate one (registry keys, sdk, dlls, etc) and then test it again, make sure your code includes the proper headers and make sure you are linking to msxfs.lib, xfs_conf.lib and xfs_supp.lib