# auto keyword not working in Dev c++

Tags: c++, vector, compiler-errors, dev-c++, auto

This was a code I wrote to see how `auto` keyword works but it didn't got compiled in Dev C++ and gave the following warning:
**[Warning] C++11 auto only available with -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11**
How to overcome this glitch and do what the warning tells to do?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<vector>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    std::vector<auto> v={2,-1,4,6,7};
    auto beg = v.begin();
    while (beg != v.end())
    {
        ++beg;
        cout<<beg;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do what the warning tells you to do - add the `-std=c++11` compilation flag

Comment: Can you please tell me how to do that?

Comment: Not so related, but are you forced to use Dev-C++? or you're using it just because it's a lightweight IDE (I remember 10MB-ish, compiler included). I last use it in 2009, and even then, it was considered an old and extremely outdated IDE (shipped with gcc version 3.x or older)

Comment: Can you please tell me the best alternative for Dev C++? What do you use currently? @JimRaynor

Comment: Code::Blocks is a good choice if you still prefer something lightweight. You can use CB it with the embedded compiler or download the latest gcc version tdm-gcc and tell the IDE to use that compiler. Or Visual Studio Code from Microsoft is now my favorite IDE (cross platform & free). Dev C++ is really buggy.

Comment: Compiler apart, you shouldn't use `auto` as the type of the vector, use `std::vector<int> v={2,-1,4,6,7};` instead. Then, being `beg` an iterator, you should dereference it when printing: `std::cout << *beg << ' ';`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to enable c++11 in the compiler using the switch instructions can be found here: [How to change mode from c++98 mode in Dev-C++ to a mode that supports C++0x (range based for)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16951376/how-to-change-mode-from-c98-mode-in-dev-c-to-a-mode-that-supports-c0x-ran)