# DEV-C++ is not displaying any available compilers any more

Tags: c, dev-c++

Yesterday I wanted to fix an issue I was having with format identifier `%Lf`, and went ahead and added flags to Dev-C++: `-std=c11` and `-D__USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO=1`. This actually fixed the issue. For further reference, you can read the actual issue I was having here: [Format specifier %Lf is giving errors for `long double` variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62359775/format-specifier-lf-is-giving-errors-for-long-double-variables)

However, when I switched on my computer today, I found that the compiler was not available any more:

[image]

How could I fix this so that I can compile code again?

**N.b.** I was using DEV-C++ with compiler `TDM-GCC 4.9.2 64-bit Release`.

**N.b.1** I am using Parallels in a MacBook Pro to be able to run Dev-C++ on Windows.

**N.b.2** I am programming in C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best thing I could do is reset the Dev-C++ settings:

```
Tool > Environment Options > Directories > Remove Settings and Exit
```

Then just reopen the program and adjust the settings as you prefer.