# Dev C++ not detecting error about using only single angle bracket with cout?

Tags: c++, dev-c++

I have a program for adjacency matrix implementation in C++.
Here is my code-

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

void addEdge(int * add){
    cout<<"Edge added successfully.\n";
    *add = 1;
}

int main(){
    
    int vertex;
    
    cout<<"Enter number of vertices in the graph: ";
    cin>>vertex;
    
    int adjMat[vertex][vertex];
    
    for(int i=0;i<vertex;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<vertex;j++){
            adjMat[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }
    
    cout<<"\n";
    cout<<"Add edges (from and to): ";
    int from,to;
    while(cin>>from>>to){
        if((from >= vertex || from < 1) || (to >= vertex || to < 1)){
            cout<"Warning: Out of bound index.\n";
        }else{
            addEdge(&adjMat[--from][--to]);
        }
    }
    
    cout<<"\n";
    for(int i=0;i<vertex;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<vertex;j++){
            cout<<adjMat[i][j]<<" ";
        }
        cout<<"\n";
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

In my program, by mistake, I wrote an error and compiled the program but the dev C++ compiler is not giving error for that and the program is running fine.
Here is that part-

```
while(cin>>from>>to){
        if((from >= vertex || from < 1) || (to >= vertex || to < 1)){
            cout<"Warning: Out of bound index.\n";
        }else{
            addEdge(&adjMat[--from][--to]);
        }
    }
```

I am getting the correct error message from other compilers.

Comment: `int adjMat[vertex][vertex];` this is invalid in C++

Comment: Dev c++ is not a compiler its an IDE. If you are on MS Windows your compiler used in dev c++ is likely some old version of mingw which you can replace and upgrade using msys2. [https://www.msys2.org/](https://www.msys2.org/)

Comment: *I am getting the correct error message from other compilers.* -- Visual C++ will refuse to compile your code due to the invalid C++ syntax `int adjMat[vertex][vertex];`.

Comment: @drescherjm: mingw (or msys2) isn't a compiler any more than Dev C++ is.  Maybe the compiler is g++?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The compiler is taking advantage of `ostream`'s `operator bool`. Before C++ 11, it was implemented as `operator void *` and returned a `void*` rather than `bool` resulting in a syntactically legal (but logically incorrect) pointer < pointer comparison. You've found one of many good reasons the operator was replaced with the modern `bool` version.

The suggestions of the commenters below the question of don't use such an ancient compiler hold, but depending on the age of your Dev-C++ install, the simplest solution may be to [turn on C++11 support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16951376/how-to-change-mode-from-c98-mode-in-dev-c-to-a-mode-that-supports-c0x-ran). If your copy of Dev-C++ is too old for that, and you still want to use it, I join drescherjm in recommending you replace the compiler it came with with an up-to-date compiler from msys2. [Here are good instructions on installing msys2 and its GCC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30069830/how-to-install-mingw-w64-and-msys2).

If you want to keep using Dev C++ but don't care about the version, [here's a link to the most up-to-date version that I'm aware of](https://www.embarcadero.com/free-tools/dev-cpp). It comes bundled with GCC 9.3, which is only a year old at the time of writing and supports C++17.