# Trash in operating memory with dynamic arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, memory, dynamic

I've tried to make an algorithm, which counts how many numbers are divided without a remainder. Code works, but every time I run it, I'm getting "trash" numbers in my output. I'm using dynamic arrays to solve a problem.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

 int main() 
 {
    int N = 30;

    int *data = new int [N];

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        for (int c = 1; c < N; c++)
        {
            if (i % c == 0)
            {
                data[c] += 1;
             }
         }
     }

     for (int k = 1; k < N; k++)
     {
        cout << data[k] << endl;
     }

     delete [] data;
 }
```

I've expected to have, at least, what C++ Shell says: http://cpp.sh/6xtc

```
100
50
34
25
20
17
15
13
12
10
10
9
8
8
7
7
6
6
6
5
5
5
5
5
4
4
4
4
4
```

, but got in different IDE the same result:

```
100
11932994
34
25
20
17
15
13
12
620757039
37045
11951945
8
11927896
7
7
7290
158
6
5
5
570425383
37040
11951941
4
11927892
4
1835102827
859059803
```

Comment: *Code works, but every time I run it, I'm getting "trash" numbers in my output.* This sentences consists of two irreconcilable parts.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You do

```
int *data = new int [N];
```

And allocate an N-sized array. Then you immediately start trying to increment the values in it:

```
data[c] += 1;
```

But what was in there to begin with?

If you want to guarantee that all the values will be initialized to 0, per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3761217/2602718) you can allocate your array with:

```
int *data = new int [N]();
//                    ^^^^
```

<Obligatory "you should just be using [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)!" comment here.\>

<sup>(But actually though, vectors would make this way easier and avoid this issue entirely)</sup>

Comment: I'm thinking of a use of "trash information" which I initialized to 0. Could it be used somewhere else in other important running programs on computer and I've just interrupted a process?

Comment: @Pr.Germux I'm not entirely sure I understand your question here, but when you do `new int [N]();` you're saying "Please give me enough consecutive blocks of memory to store N ints" and the computer goes and finds a chunk of memory that big that no one else is using and puts a sticky-note with your name on it there :)

Answer (score 3):

```
data[c] += 1;
```

You add something to an *uninitialized* value. data[c] was not necessarily 0 before that. `new` does not initialize a dynamic array to zero.

Quit all new/delete and use std::vector<>. And, do learn to use the debugger - really helpful in this case.