# std::vector faster than plain array?

Tags: c++, performance, stl, vector

I have just tried to benchmark `std::sort` on both `std::vector<std::pair<float, unsigned int>>` (filled with push_back operation) and plain `std::pair<float, unsigned int>> *` array (allocated using new and then filled one by one). The compare function just compared the float parts of the pairs.

Surprisingly, when used on 16M values, on std::vector it took only about 1940 ms but on the array it was about 2190 ms. Can anybody explain how can be the vector faster? Is it due to cacheing, or is just array version of std::sort poorly implemented?

`gcc (GCC) 4.4.5 20110214 (Red Hat 4.4.5-6)`

`Intel(R) Core(TM) i7 CPU 870  @ 2.93GHz - cache size 8192 KB` (the computer has two quad-core CPUs but I assume the sort is only single-threaded)

**EDIT:** Now you can call me dumbass, but when I tried to reproduce the code I used for the measurements (I have already deleted the original one) I cannot reproduce the results - now the array version takes about 1915 +- 5ms (measured on 32 runs). I can only swear I have run the test on 10 measurements three times (manually) with similar results, but this is not a rigorous proof.

There was probably some bug in the original code, background process seems unprobable because I have alternated measurements of vector and array versions and the vector results hold and no user was logged in.

Please, consider this question as **closed**. Thanks for your efforts.

Comment: How many times did you run the test? one time is not stasticly accurate at all.

Comment: You should provide the exact testing protocole you did follow. For example, if you didn't execute your tests more than one time for each, or if you did both tests in the same execution(s), then test isn't relevant.

Comment: On my `i7 920 @ 2.67 GHz` with `gcc 4.5.2`, I get `770 - 780 ms` for the vector and `630 - 650 ms` for the array. What optimization options did you use? (I used `-march=native -O3`, array and vector contained identical 16000000 pairs of random numbers)

Comment: Were the input arrays sorted identically to begin with?  How many other things is your machine doing?  There are typically 100 threads on a machine, and if some of those are running it will affect performance.  The difference there is only 10%.

Comment: @Cubbi: Weird, too. GCC vectors use pointers as iterators when compiled with optimisation and not in debug mode. So the results should be *identical* and yours look significantly different.

Comment: @Konrad Given that he doesn't show us any of the code he's actually measuring, who knows?  But the difference isn't very large (and he doesn't say how he measured it, either).

Comment: Are you using the same input data in both tests?

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph my test prog: https://ideone.com/hXv9V (ideone runs them in exactly the same time!). Also, recompiling with gcc 4.6.0 or 4.6.1 makes them run in the same time on my system (both 640 - 650 ms). Must be something with my 4.5.2 setup.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3664272/14065

Comment: Okay, I have used the `-O3` switch, but the code was not compiled with `-march=native`
The data were identical in all 10 measurements, the standard deviation is in orders of miliseconds (for both tests). I know that to be statistically correct, more measurements are required but the results are pretty stable even for this number of measurements.

Answer (score 12):

> `std::vector<std::pair<float, unsigned int>>` (filled with push_back operation)

This stores all the data continguously, so memory locality is very good

> `std::pair<float, unsigned int>> *` array (allocated using new and then filled one by one)

This scatters the data all over memory.

You've set up a very unfair comparison between `vector` and a simple array.  The extra indirection involved in the array case is going to hurt, the lack of locality is going to kill cache performance.  I'm surprised you don't see a bigger win in favor of contiguous storage.

Comment: I don't think that this is right.  If I understand correctly, the second allocates an array of `std::pair<float, unsigned int>>`, using array new.  Locality should be exactly the same.

Comment: @James: That's not what the question literally says, although I understand how you could interpret it that way (and your interpretation may very well be correct).  The question says he has an array of pointers to pairs.  This is why questions without code, and performance questions especially, are a terrible idea.

Comment: @Ben I understood it that he called `std::sort` on 1) an `std::vector<std::pair<float, unsigned int> >` and 2) a `std::pair<float, unsigned int>*`, but it's far from clear.  (But I'd expect a far greater difference if he really did use an array of pointers in the second case.)

Comment: @James: If the allocations were done with good time locality, space locality would be mediocre and not outright terrible.  That's the best explanation I can offer.

Comment: The recursive nature of quicksort along with the cache will make locality less important than you may think. Once you recurse down to some level, all the data is in cache and only indirection is causing a penalty, not locality. I'm assuming quicksort here.

Comment: @phkahler: Even quicksort has to access some of the same items repeatedly.  If items are individually allocated, often adding a heap header to each, fewer items fit in cache.  Anyway, I don't think gcc `std::sort` is quicksort.

Comment: @Ben Voigt It's a variant on quick sort, which shifts to a heap sort if it finds it's recursing too deeply, and uses insertion sort when the number of elements in the partition becomes small enough.

Comment: @Ben: Sorry, I have doubled the `*` and array in the description, James understood me correctly. It was just an array of pairs, there was no another level of indirection, so the locality is really the same.

Answer (score 2):

They will use the same version of `sort`. It's quite likely random CPU effects, like caching or thread context switches.

Comment: How do you know they use the same version of sort? As I recall it is not specified how they are implemented in the ISO specification. They probably just use the same interface/template.

Comment: @Yet - If he is using `gcc (GCC) 4.4.5 20110214` we know what std::sort looks like.

Comment: @Yet Another Geek: Because vector iterators and array iterators are the same thing in release builds.

Comment: @DeadMG I thought array iterated using pointers, and vector through some kind of typesafe class based reference

Comment: @Yet Another Geek: In release builds, `vector<T>::iterator` can be typedefed as `T*`. Their specification is identical.

Answer (score 1):

Did you use `-O3` to compile your code?

If not, do it. All other benchmark results are meaningless, especially for template code.

Did you run the test many times?

This is done to prevent things like interrupts and or caching to have to much of an impact on your result.

Don't use floatint point comparison or arithmetic for benchmarks. The results depend heavily on the compiler, platform, compiler options etc.

How was your testdata created?

The time required by most sorting algorithm changes depending on the sorting of the input data.

Which method for measuring time did you use? Clock cycles? A timer?

Anyway, writing benchmarks that provide reliable results is not as easy as it might seem at first. Don't use a benchmark to determine what the proper code for your problem is.