# Why should someone prefer vectors over arrays?

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C++ STL vector vs array in the real world](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6462985/c-stl-vector-vs-array-in-the-real-world)

*To start of I have a little below average knowledge of C++ and advanced knowledge of C* 
Many times, I want to ask something code related and include or refer to some code and an `array` comes up everyone instantly lock on this aspect and suggest I should instead use a `vector`, even if it doesn't have to do anything related to my problem.

The problem is that this is the way I learned how to use C++, obviously something I inherited from learning plain C first, and I am quite used to it, although I feel confident about using vectors also, I just prefer `arrays` over `vectors`.

My questions are why should someone use a `vector` instead of an `array`, what does he earn by doing so, even if he is quite used to arrays?
Also if `arrays` are not preferred over `vectors` why doesn't everyone simply use vectors for everything?

Comment: The question is why would anyone prefer _arrays_ over _vectors_, and handling all the details themselves...

Comment: The real distinction is between *dynamically allocated* arrays and vectors, of course. Fixed-size arrays are perfectly fine, though you should use `std::array` for those.

Comment: @KerrekSB: The distinction is between _automatically-allocated_ arrays and vectors, of course. Dynamically-allocated arrays _are_ vectors, at some level of abstraction.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Vectors have a dimension that may be provided at run-time, such as a user-provided value or something derived from a file's contents.

The size of an array, by contrast, must be *hard-coded* into your program. It is fixed. <sup>†</sup>

> why doesn't everyone simply use vectors for everything?

There is a run-time performance cost for using vectors over arrays when you don't need to. Personally I've never written code in which this is a bottleneck and therefore rarely use raw arrays; still, such scenarios *do* exist.

---

<sup>†</sup> The exception is when you create a block of memory (an "array" in some sense) *dynamically* with `new[]`; this is the exact language feature that is encapsulated by `std::vector`.

Comment: But using `new` on an array can make dynamically allocated arrays or am I wrong somewhere?

Comment: @Aposperite: Sure. `std::vector` is a wrapper around that process so the same logic applies in that case. (Strictly speaking you don't create an "array" in that case but a "block of memory", but on neither an abstract nor a practical level can I defend the difference.)

Comment: So in general there is no practical difference between `dynamically allocated arrays` and `vectors` other than the fact you can presumably handle vectors easier and more bug-free than arrays?

Comment: @Aposperite: Sort of. More or less. Less because `std::vector` is an object wrapper and, as such, you can just pass it around with worrying about ownership. If you try to handle a pointer-to-a-dynamically-allocated-array yourself then you get into a pickle pretty easily. Also a `std::vector` object will handle _all_ the hard work for you, such as resizing the array if you need.

Comment: Not sure if you are talking about the `new T[n]` case or the `std::vector` case, but `new T[n]` definitely *does* create an array. See the last sentence of 5.3.4 §1, for example: " If it is an array, the new-expression returns a pointer to the initial element of the array."

Answer (score 0):

One of the reasons is the performance behavior of each container, [as explained here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/):

> Many containers have several member functions in common, and share
>   functionalities. The decision of which type of container to use for a
>   specific need does not generally depend only on the functionality
>   offered by the container, but also on the efficiency of some of its
>   members (complexity). This is especially true for sequence containers,
>   which offer different trade-offs in complexity between
>   inserting/removing elements and accessing them.

Answer (score 0):

Vectors

- do their own allocation and deallocation of memory
- resize automatically when expanding
- can be used where STL containers can, which includes many many algorithms and methods
- have many other methods that are useful

Arrays

- take less memory overall
- Are used in C code, so are used for reverse compatibility

Comment: Vectors can be used in a compatible fashion with _C_ apis as well, I don't think that last point holds...

Comment: I don't buy the compatibility argument. If you're interfacing with C code, you can provide a pointer to `std::vector` data precisely as easily as you can to array data.

Comment: Also if I am not mistaken `vectors` are a *bit* slower than `arrays` and this could be a problem in big programs. Right? Or this is another myth too?

Comment: @Aposperite: That's a myth, to a degree. There is a tiny amount of overhead when the vector is created, but even in "big programs" you should be coding in such a way that this makes zero difference i.e. not creating a vector (_or_ an array!) in a tight loop. No difference in other usage.

Answer (score 0):

The main reason is that the size of a `std::vector` can be decided at run time and is resizeable.  The vector also supports iterators, which means it works well with many stl algorithms such as `std::for_each` or `std::anyof`.  Vectors can also be used to allocate memory in a safe way and that is compatible with C functions.

If you are using the Windows API, `std::vector` is very useful with the get-size-get-data paradigm that is used in many functions.  This is where you typically call the same function twice, the first time to get the data size, the second time to actually read the data.  For example:

```
DWORD size = 0;
DWORD type = 0;
if ( RegQueryValueEx( HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, 
    L"SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\.NETFramework\\InstallRoot", 
    nullptr, 
    &type, 
    nullptr, 
    &size ) == ERROR_SUCCESS )
{
    std::vector<BYTE> data( size );
    if ( RegQueryValueEx( HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, 
        L"SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\.NETFramework\\InstallRoot", 
        nullptr, 
        &type, 
        &data[0], 
        &size ) == ERROR_SUCCESS )
    {
      //We have read the data
    }
}
```

The size of an array is decided at compile-time and cannot be resized.  Arrays are still used in C.

Comment: `std::array` supports iterators too.