# Why do I have a run-time Error inserting values into classes in C++

Tags: c++, pointers, runtime-error

I would like some help in getting this sorted out.
I have a class named Grades that contains a pointer to class Student.

```
class Grades {
    int numofstuds;
    Student** studs;
public:
    void insertgrades();
    void printgrades();
};

class Student {
    int id;
    int grade;
public:
    void getId();
    void getGrade();
    void printgrade();
};
```

I am trying to insert students into the array studs:

```
void Grades::insertgrades() {
    int i;
    cout << "How many students ?" << endl;
    cin >> numofstuds;
    studs = new Student*[numofstuds];
    for (i = 0; i < numofstuds; i++) {
        studs[i]->getId();
        studs[i]->getGrade();
    }
}
```

'insertgrades' is an inner function inside the class Grades.
getId and getGrade are inner functions inside the class 'Student', they work well I have checked them:

```
void Student::getId() {
    do {
        cout << "Enter id" << endl;
        cin >> id;
    } while (id<0);
}
void Student::getGrade() {
    cout << "Enter grade:" << endl;
    cin >> grade;
}
```

this is the main:

```
int main() {
    Grades a;
    a.insertgrades();
    return 0;
}
```

As soon as I am trying to insert values into Id or grades I immediately have a run-time error.
Please help!
Isan.

Comment: Is this schoolwork? Because you really better use standard containers instead of raw pointer arrays.

Comment: Why are you using a double pointer?  From the way you are using it you should just have `Student* studs;`

Comment: It is a school work actually. I have decided to use studs** because later on deleting/adding new students will be easier :)

Comment: You allocated an array of `Student*` with `new Student*[numofstuds]`, but those pointers are not valid.

Comment: Be careful not to cause memory leak!

Comment: This would be a good exercise to use a debugger.

Comment: @IsanRivkin `because later on..` Later on, you should get the chance to learn how to use containers and not double stars.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews can you give me more info so I can research that ?

Comment: Your IDE may have a debugger for C++, so you should search the documentation of your IDE.  Otherwise search the internet for "C++ debugger" and also insert your platform.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MikeCAT's answer is correct, however please take note that what you are doing is VERY likely to cause memory leaks.
Obviously I haven't seen your class destructor - However unless you are carefully iterating over every pointer in Studs, calling delete [], then calling delete [] on Studs - You will end up in a big pile of leaked memory.

I'm going to assume from your use of the language you are more familair with reference counted languages like VisualBasic - in C++ allocating Memory with New provides no assurance of garbage collection.
As your not storing `numberofstuds` you will never be able to free the memory allocated in MikeCAT's answer.

If you can make use of C++11, consider the following code snippet for a memory-safe way to handle this problem.

```
#include <memory>
#include <vector>
class Student;
class Grades {
    int numofstuds;
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Student> > studs;
public:
    void insertgrades();
    void printgrades();
};
```

and the insert grades routine:

```
void Grades::insertgrades() {
    int i;
    std::cout << "How many students ?" << std::endl;
    std::cin >> numofstuds;
    studs.resize(numofstuds);
    for (auto Each_Student : studs) 
    {
        Each_Student.reset(new student())
        Each_Student->getId();
        Each_Student->getGrade();
    }
}
```

If however you *must* use raw pointers (older compiler, or *poor grading body*), please consider the following destructor in addition to MadCat's answer

```
~Grades()
{
    for (i = 0; i < numofstuds; i++) 
    {
        delete studs[i];
    }
delete [] studs;
}
```

## [/edit]

I'd like to add that your approach to storing the data isn't *wrong* however you can do it much more simply.
Rather than creating an array of pointers to store the data - you can allocate an array of the objects instead.

```
class Grades 
{
    //snipped out everything else
    Student* studs;
}
void Grades::insertgrades() 
{
    int i;
    cout << "How many students ?" << endl;
    cin >> numofstuds;
    studs = new Student[numofstuds];
    for (i = 0; i < numofstuds; i++) {
        studs[i].getId();
        studs[i].getGrade();
    }
}
```

In C++ a pointer is "The address in memory of data", an array is "the address in memory of a *set* of data", as such the following code should help you comprehend why the above works.

```
char A;
//the following pointer will *point to the location of A*
char * A_p = & A;
char Array[100];
//this pointer will *point to the data set Array*
char * Array_p = Array;
//this pointer *points to a newly allocated set of data*
char * B_p = new char [100];
//indeed, we can also do this 

//Set A to first character of array
A = *Array_p
A = Array_P[0]
A = *Array
A = Array[0]
//all of these do the same thing, as *when using an array, you're really using a pointer

delete [] B_P;
```

Comment: I'd postulate the `std::unique_ptr` is a better fit here. There is no sharing of ownership.

Comment: I still don't know what <vector> is or how to use that library, I did forget to delete the pointers thanks for reminding me that, also thanks for the code snippets I am going to study right now that code.

Comment: @StoryTeller using a unique_ptr in this situation isn't easily done - Remember that unique_ptr isn't copyable. As such it cannot be stored in a stl container!

Comment: @IsanRivkin The vector is basically an array that can be resized! Something c++ without the STL doesn't have.  
What your tutor is trying to do is teach you how to dynamically allocate memory (I'm actually going to amend my answer about that in a moment). Allocating memory with raw pointers is how you dynamically-create an array without the use of std::vector.

Comment: @JohnBargman, actually it can. You just have to remember to move it when inserting. STL containers can handle `std::unique_ptr` quite well nowadays. It's not c++03 with `boost::unique_ptr` anymore :)

Comment: @StoryTeller Surely it doesn't matter if I std::move it into the container. As if the container resizes, or moves it will use the copy-constructor?

Comment: @StoryTeller I stand corrected! I hadn't taken note that STL containers now handle movable objects.
Thank you for the update.

Answer (score 2):

You created only "boxes" to store pointers to `Student`, but you didn't store valid pointers.

You have to create Students before using.

```
void Grades::insertgrades() {
    int i;
    cout << "How many students ?" << endl;
    cin >> numofstuds;
    studs = new Student*[numofstuds];
    for (i = 0; i < numofstuds; i++) {
        studs[i] = new Student(); // add this line
        studs[i]->getId();
        studs[i]->getGrade();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why even do that?  We can just change it to `Student* studs;` in the class and now we do not have to levels of pointers and two level of deletions to have to maintain.

Comment: @NathanOliver, well it's schoolwork, and the professor already decided that torturous use of raw `new` and `delete` is better than using standard containers. So may as well suffer on two levels.

Comment: But you're using `new` incorrectly in this case.  It's one thing to teach `new`, its another when you're told to use it like this.  A *much* more better use of `new` would have you build a *real* dynamic array class.  You learn `new` / `delete`, copy construction, assignment, etc. Much more educative than throwing `new` anywhere in code and hoping it works.

Comment: Your professor needs education.

If he wants you to learn Pointers however - you may want to brush up on the fundamentals. I'm about to post an answer myself that may help

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the immediate response!
I have solved this thanks to @MikeCAT.
I added another func to actually create a student:

```
Student* createstud() {
    Student* News = new Student;
    return News;
}
```

And then I change my func like that:

```
void Grades::insertgrades() {
    int i;
    cout << "How many students ?" << endl;
    cin >> numofstuds;
    studs = new Student*[numofstuds];
    for (i = 0; i < numofstuds; i++) {
        **studs[i] = createstud();**
        studs[i]->getId();
        studs[i]->getGrade();
    }
}
```

Not sure why is it bad idea to create Students** array, since I am planning to delete students in the future so it is easier to change pointers inside the array, no ?

Comment: Read up http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6462985/c-stl-vector-vs-array-in-the-real-world

Comment: Please do also take care to delete ALL allocated memory (see my answer).

And take a look into std::shared_ptr, and the other new managed pointer-types.