# Automatically deallocate array?

Tags: c++, memory-management

I'm looking for a way to automatically deallocate an array of `wchar_t`s – kind of like an autopointer (I'm not really aquainted with std::auto_ptr, but I think it cannot be used for arrays).

The code I have right now is this:

```
/* volume is of type wstring,
 * hr is of type HRESULT, 
 * VSS_PWSZ equals wchar_t* 
 */

VSS_PWSZ pwszVolume = new wchar_t[volume.size() + 1];
std::copy(volume.begin(), volume.end(), &pwszVolume);
pwszVolume[volume.size()] = 0;

hr = pDiffMgmt->QueryDiffAreasOnVolume(pwszVolume, &pEnumMgmt);

delete[] pwszVolume;
pwszVolume = NULL;
```

I don't really get why this stupid function cannot take a `const wchar_t*`, otherwise I could just pass `volume.c_str()`.

So far so good, I think my code solves this problem, but now the memory management is getting more complicated: I would have to duplicate the `delete[]` code to account for exceptions which might be thrown (and which I do not want to catch at this point.)

Is there a way I can get `pwszVolume` to be deallocated automatically when the current scope is left?

Comment: Took a second for me to remember this - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use std::vector<wchar_t> it is your basic C++ array (or std::wstring if you want to manipulate it like a string).

```
std::vector<wchar_t> pwszVolume(volume.begin(), volume.end());
pwszVolume.push_back(0);

hr = pDiffMgmt->QueryDiffAreasOnVolume(&pwszVolume[0], &pEnumMgmt);
```

The question may be. What does QueryDiffAreasOnVolume() do with the data?
Maybe you do not need to copy it out.

Comment: If that function never actually writes to the array in its first argument, you could cast away const-ness. If you're very, very, very sure.

Comment: You can construct a `vector` from a range directly, no need for `std::copy`. Use `std::vector<wchar_t> pwszVolume(volume.begin(), volume.end()); pwszVolume.push_back(0);`.

Comment: `wstring` doesn't help me, but thanks for this `vector` code. (The code with `push_back` instead of `copy` can be slower if it just hits a boundary where a `resize` must occur on the vector, but I'm still going for this because of the conciseness.)

Comment: @Felix Dombek: What is the type of volume? We may not need to push the '0' if it is already a string with the trailing '\0'

Comment: @Martin: `volume` is a `wstring` so I guess I can indeed assume that the trailing NUL char is copied automatically.

Comment: @Felix Dombek: Unfortunately not. Unless you explicitly added a '\0' into the string then the terminating '\0' is not part of the length and only technically appears with a call to c_str(). But I believe in the new standard has data() returns a pointer to an area that is '\0' terminated. So you may be able to do this: `newV(&v.data[0], &v.data[v.size() + 1])` but I would validate that before taking my word.

Answer (score 4):

`std::unique_ptr` can be used with arrays as follows:

```
std::unique_ptr<wchar_t[]> pwszVolume(new wchar_t[volume.size() + 1]);
```

Another option is [`std::array`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb983093.aspx).

But I agree with Martin's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6831647/automatically-deallocate-array/6831689#6831689) that you should just use an `std::vector` unless you really cannot afford to have the couple of extra pointers that the vector class holds.

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, `std::vector` is the preferred solution, by far.
Otherwise (if e.g. you originally get the pointer from third party
software which you cannot modify), there's `boost::scoped_array` or
`boost::shared_array`.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap wchar_t* inside a class, deallocate memory on destruct-or and you have an object that will be automatically deallocated when it loses scope.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want the overhead from std::vector, use [boost::array](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/array.html). It is your basic C++ array with static size.

Comment: Or there is [std::tr1::array](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb983093.aspx) if boost is not an option

Comment: What overhead? see http://stackoverflow.com/q/3664272/14065 But I generally agree that std:array or boost::array is a good alternative.

Comment: @Martin: That link you show is a comparison between dynamically allocated arrays.  The tr1 array is not dynamically allocated.  Surely there is an overhead in dynamic allocation.

Comment: @Benjamin Lindley: I was not aware of that. I am still not fully familiar with the new standard. But that's interesting, why would I use a std::array over a normal language array?

Comment: @Martin: A few reasons.  It avoids bugs associated with pointer decay.  It has convenience functions like `begin` and `end`, as well as things that are harder to do with pointers like `rbegin` and `rend`.  Bounds checking with `at()`, etc...