# Is Boost/STL slow with regard to high performance computing?

Tags: c++, performance, boost, stl

Apologies for [another internet forum quote](http://www.elitetrader.com/vb/showthread.php?s=9498c2946333c7e233fb83cea6330de0&threadid=204368&perpage=6&pagenumber=6), but I thought this was interesting and wanted to ask:

> C++ is faster if you chuck the "safety" features of programming
>   languages and avoid things like STL, and Boost. In raw bytes to bytes
>   C++ is faster, but then again so is C.
>
> The moment you add the baggage of STL, and Boost you are slower than
>   well written C# code. The advantage that the C# JIT and Java jit have
>   is that those safety features are well optimized. C++ safety features
>   rely on the optimization of the compiler.
>
> Thus if you are not careful with your STL, and Boost code you will
>   have a lame duck of an application.

I agree about ridding of the safety features, but I have seen a lot of high frequency job adverts and they all ask for Boost experience. Surely Boost cannot be something bad to producing fast code? Or is this person merely stating theoretically if you simply manipulated at byte level it would be faster?

*Edit : The quote is about STL and Boost, thus I added the STL tag.*

Comment: Whoever said that does not know what he is talking about.

Comment: Don't agree that STL or BOOST make you slower. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3664272/stdvector-is-so-much-slower-than-plain-arrays/3664349#3664349

Comment: Don't forget that in job adverts, they are probably looking more for people who write *correct* code first, with performance being a secondary (though still important) concern.

Comment: If you were really doing "high performance computing" I'd seriously doubt you'd be using something like C# or Java. Every language has their place, but I don't think HPC is in the realm of C# or Java yet.

Comment: Whoever said that is just trolling or ill-informed. Either way, it's flat out wrong.

Comment: can you provide a reference to your source that says C# is faster than C++? C++ devs have good reasons to be skeptical ;)

Comment: I only agree on this little part : *If you are not careful with ...*

Comment: @overcoder: I would even disagree with that. Though you can make it slower if done badly the same can be said of any language construct (it is not something that is unique to STL/Boost). I would say that the STL has been designed to be very efficient out of the box with little or no help.

Answer (score 23):

**No**

boost and the C++ standard libraries are used to produce extremely fast production implementations. Of course, one could improve upon those implementations *in specific scenarios* - this is analogous to writing your own allocator when you know how your execution differs from the general purpose allocators, and how to optimize for that usage. So one can of course analyze the problem and produce an optimized implementation that is faster than the general purpose implementations (or boost).

Of course, any library can also be misused, which could result in compromised execution. The short of it is that boost (a large collection of libraries) implementations are an excellent starting point for fast implementations. If you need it to be faster than boost, determine the problem and improve it.

Many C++ developers are concerned about performance; in general, more than other languages. boost is generally well regarded, peer reviewed, and the implementations are used to test and form the basis for standard library features.

## -----

***Thanks*** to Justin for letting me share his answer on the closed question: <sup><sub>-- Seth</sub></sup>

> Quite the opposite.
>
> Boost is *not* about safety belts.
>
> Boost is about *high level* software components, with a *high level* of abstraction This avoids the usual 'library lock-in' seen with other frameworks/libraries<sup>1</sup>.
>
> For example, your Boost Graph library does **not** require you to switch data structures at all: you can use/adapt any data structure that performs well for your application. In the worst case, you might have to write a traits class to help Boost with the interpretation; It is precisely this trait (common to modern template libraries) that makes Boost perform like nothing else *in practice*: there won't be as much ***library impedance mismatch***. This is directly in line with C++11's new concepts around threading and move semantics: preventing even the most elementary cases of data copying.
>
> Also, all these libraries honour your own allocator implementations, allowing for unsurpassable memory management performance. You can aligned 128bit int vectors in C# - but you'll have to jump through many many hoops<sup>2</sup> and, there is *no way* you can ever make it work with the framework API's.
>
> In C++ you pay only for what you use, and Boost is entirely in that spirit.
>
> Mmmm I think I haven't quite stressed the point enough yet, but I'm done for now.
>
> Let me close by looking at it from the other side: in C# it is much harder to write performant code, because it is much harder to see what's going on behind the scenes.
>
> Once you drop behind the scenes (*unsafe mode*, *IL code*) you'll arguably be less safe than in C++, because in C++ there is a transparent policy of what happens where and how. In C# you can't even trust an `int*` that you got one line ago (because the Garbage Collector might have moved your cheese); There is no telling what the compiler 
>   and or the JIT engine will make of your nice generic code<sup>3</sup>.
>
> In short: you can write bad code just anywhere, but Boost cannot be blamed. STL can only be blamed for insane raw performance<sup>4</sup>.
>
> <sup>1</sup>PoCo, Qt, MFC, WTL, whatnot....
>
> <sup>2</sup>[Mono SIMD](http://tirania.org/blog/archive/2008/Nov-03.html)
>
> <sup>3</sup>Including numerous areas that are close to pathetic and violate the 'Principle Of Least Surprise' in a big way ([example <strike>coming</strike> when blog back online](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2011/08/23/optimization-and-generics-part-2-lambda-expressions-and-reference-types.aspx))
>
> <sup>4</sup>That `std::copy` will be statically translated in the best implementation based on SSE4, MOVSW or just plain memcpy that money can buy, and yet you don't have to even write a single letter different from copying a `istream` to a `set`, so to speak.

Comment: can I borrow a spot for my already-written answer? I hate to just drop it in the waste bin :)

Comment: @sehe i don't see why not. go ahead, but please add a note to your answer within an answer to avoid confusion =)