# optimizing `std::vector operator []` (vector access) when it becomes a bottleneck

Tags: c++, multithreading, vector, stl

gprof says that my high computing app spends 53% of its time inside `std::vector <...> operator [] (unsigned long)`, 32% of which goes to one heavily used vector. Worse, I suspect that my parallel code failing to scale beyond 3-6 cores is due to a related memory bottleneck. While my app does spend a lot of time accessing and writing memory, it seems like I should be able (or at least try) to do better than 52%. Should I try using dynamic arrays instead (size remains constant in most cases)? Would that be likely to help with possible bottlenecks?

Actually, my preferred solution would be to solve the bottleneck and leave the vectors as is for convenience. Based on the above, are there any likely culprits or solutions (tcmalloc is out)?

Comment: Well, is it taking 53% of one millionth of a nanosecond? If so, it's doing really well. I don't think taking 53% of the time is a bad thing in itself, unless that time is very big. How long is the program taking overall, and related to what?

Comment: Well, `std::vector` basically *is* a dynamic array, so changing that won't do any good. Did you actually compile with optimizations / release mode enabled?

Comment: AFAIK, gprof can't profile inlined code. `[]` should be inlined, if it's showing up my guess is that it's not.

Comment: @MattMunson yes, obviously. I was asking what the total running time is (is it one millionth of a nanosecond? If so... etc)

Comment: @Xeo with g++, is optimization/release mode enabled by default? I do know that debug mode is not enabled.

Comment: @Matt: Optimization is enabled with the `-O` flag. Default is `-O0` (no optimization). Try `-O2` (or higher).

Comment: @Seth ah sorry, its 53% both of 4 seconds and of 10 seconds (2 different runs).

Comment: Did you compile with the optimizations turned on? The [vector is probably as fast as normal array](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3664349/14065).

Comment: @Xeo i used optimization and it got rid of the vectors and cut my execution time in half! Thanks. Unfortunately the scaling problem is unaffected.

Comment: @MattMunson I don't understand how concurrency/parallelism has to do with your vector from your question

Comment: @Ghita my parallelism is hitting a bottleneck that I strongly suspect has to do with memory access. Meanwhile, `operator[]` has to do with memory access as well. I thought that if my program is doing 50% of its time in `operator[]`, that could be the culprit, or at least supports my suspicion intense memory access is causing a bottleneck somehow.

Comment: Two things: First: compile with *maximum* optimizations; asking about performance is utterly meaningless otherwise. Second: make sure your concurrency actually makes sense. Is there a lot of locking going on?

Comment: @GMan There is essentially no locking going on. Does -O2 give maximum optimization?

Comment: @MattMunson: `03` does; be sure to read the compiler documentation on this subject.

Comment: @GMan Cool. `O1``O2`and`O3` all test equally fast: 2X as fast as `O0`. I guess that means that whatever is making the difference comes into effect with `O1`. Is that useful somehow?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you examine your memory access pattern itself? It might be inefficient - cache unfriendly.

Comment: @Matt Munson: Good question, actually. I don't know of any tools that can help you in doing that, so I can only suggest analyzing the algorithm.

Comment: What would I look for? what are the characteristics of a cache unfriendly algorithm?

Comment: @Matt Munson: memory loves sequential forward access. When you read memory address A, some further addresses are pre-cached. Also, memory is accessed in burst mode in this case, transferring not single elements, but blocks. This all changes if you try reading memory bacwards, even is sequential manner. And there's nothing worse than completely random access of a big memory block. What's the number of elements of your vector, BTW?

Comment: it may be a bit hard to sum up quickly. This line is the main workhorse of my app: `add_vector <compute_sign>( (*targ)[w], (source[q] * (syns[i].weight + syns[i].rmod)) );` its inside 3 loops, two of which are contingent on if statements. vector `syns[]` will be 72, 36, 8, or 3 long. Would you be willing to take a look at my code in chat?

Comment: @MattMunson the obvious things to ask would be how are the iterations performed (to avoid jumping around too much) and how you divided the workload among the different processes (avoid false sharing) The next thing is whether you can cache some of the intermediate results. None of those can be seen in the bit of information that you produced.

Comment: Intel makes some tools that they claim will show cache behavior and statistics.

Answer (score 2):

Did you try to use raw pointer while array accessing?

```
// regular place

for (int i = 0; i < arr.size(); ++i)
    wcout << arr[i];

// In bottleneck

int *pArr = &arr.front();

for (int i = 0; i < arr.size(); ++i)
    wcout << pArr[i];
```

Comment: That will behave exactly the same, as `vector<T>::operator[]` just forwards to its internal dynamic array.

Comment: @Xeo yeah, but maybe the forwarding is taking a relatively lot of time. Also trying this might rule out the optimisation of just using a dynamic array which the OP was thinking about doing.

Comment: @SethCarnegie: seconded. I've seen order-of-magnitude speedups between -O0 and -O2, simply because iterator forwarding got inlined.

Comment: @mosh: It doesn't use an iterator internally, just its raw pointer. It's basically `return *(ptr + pos);`.

Comment: @Xeo: there are still massive speedups when optimization in place. Fast pointer increment and better inlining are two good reasons. Profiling debug builds is somewhat pointless compared to profiling release builds.

Comment: @mosh: Well, that's for sure. Also, like MSVC, some libraries do heavy checking in debug builds (range checks, integrity checks, etc).

Comment: @Xeo: MSVC < VS2010 do range checking in `operator[]` even in release builds. Read about `_SECURE_SCL`. Reference [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa985965%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that gprof prevents functions to be inlined. Try to use another profiling method. `std::vector operator []` cannot be bottleneck because it doesn't differ much from raw array access. SGI implementaion is shown below:

```
reference operator[](size_type __n) { return *(begin() + __n); }
iterator begin() { return _M_start; }
```

Comment: gprof doesn't prevent anything - compiling with debug symbols and no optimizations is what's preventing the inlining.

Comment: @Pubby: to get things like call graph and exact call counts you need to also instrument functions. This is going to make a HUGE difference on fast executing code (basically making any number you can get out of gprof completely meaningless).

Answer (score 1):

You cannot trust `gprof` for high-speed code profiling, you should instead use a passive profiling method like `oprofile` to get the real picture.

As an alternative you could profile by manual code alteration (e.g. calling a computation 10 times instead of one and checking how much the execution time increases). Note that this is however going to be influenced by cache issues so YMMV.

Comment: I tried `oprofile` and `perf` and unfortunately they are not viable on the virtualized (EC2 HPC) machines that are my target platform. I don't suppose there's a convenient way around that?

Answer (score 0):

The vector class is heavily liked and provides a certain amount of convenience, at the expense of performance, which is fine when you don't particularly need performance.

If you really need performance, it won't hurt you too much to bypass the vector class and go directly to a simple old hand-made array, whether statically or dynamically allocated. Then 1) the time you currently spend indexing should essentially disappear, speeding up your app by that amount, and 2) you can move on to whatever the "next big thing" is that takes time in your app.

EDIT:
Most programs have a lot more room for speedup than you might suppose. I made a [walk-through project](https://sourceforge.net/projects/randompausedemo/files/) to illustrate this. If I can summarize it really quickly, it goes like this:

- Original time is 2.7 msec per "job" (the number of "jobs" can be varied to get enough run-time to analyze it).
- First cut showed roughly 60% of time was spent in vector operations, including indexing, appending, and removing. I replaced with a similar vector class from MFC, and time decreased to 1.8 msec/job. (That's a 1.5x or 50% speedup.)
- Even with that array class, roughly 40% of time was spent in the [] indexing operator. I wanted it to index directly, so I forced it to index directly, not through the operator function. That reduced time to 1.5 msec/job, a 1.2x speedup.
- Now roughly 60% of the time is adding/removing items in arrays. An additional fraction was spent in "new" and "delete". I decided to chuck the arrays and do two things. One was to use do-it-yourself linked lists, and to pool used objects. The first reduced time to 1.3 msec (1.15x). The second reduced it to 0.44 msec (2.95x).
- Of that time, I found that about 60% of the time was in code I had written to do indexing into the list (as if it were an array). I decided that could be done instead just by having a pointer directly into the list. Result: 0.14 msec (3.14x).
- Now I found that nearly all the time was being spent in a line of diagnostic I/O I was printing to the console. I decided to get rid of that: 0.0037 msec (38x).

I could have kept going, but I stopped.
The overall time per job was reduced by a compounded factor of about 700x.

What I want you to take away is if you need performance bad enough to deviate from what might be considered the accepted ways of doing things, you don't have to stop after one "bottleneck".
Just because you got a big speedup doesn't mean there are no more.
In fact the next "bottleneck" might be bigger than the first, in terms of speedup factor.
So raise your expectations of speedup you can get, and go for broke.

Comment: What performance expense do you perceive when using `std::vector<>` with optimizations enabled? I'd warrant that there are _none_. Profiling code with optimizations disabled is just silly.

Comment: @ildjarn: You would hope that enabling optimizations would cause [] to be inlined. The problem with that is it's hard to do further sampling. On the other hand you can force it to index directly, without losing the ability to do further sampling. If you lose the ability to do the diagnostic sampling, the progression of speedups stalls. Also, notice that while direct indexing saved time, getting rid of the vectors altogether saved even more time, *in this program*.

Comment: It sounds like you're pointing out the downsides of various profiling approaches moreso than explaining any reason why `std::vector<>` would be any slower than a plain C-array with optimizations enabled.

Comment: @ildjarn: Yeah. Suppose there were a contest. Who can write a program to get a specific job done, on a specific machine, in the least time, nothing else being more important? The approach I prefer is to turn on optimization at the end. After I've squeezed out every cycle I can, then let the compiler do its thing.

Comment: @ildjarn: See, in the initial version of the program, I used vectors because, well, why not? They work. But it turns out, after some tuning, they were the "bottleneck" and a linked list would save time. That just confirms that different data structures are better under different circumstances. The important thing is how you find out what to fix, and that successive fixes generate compounded speedup factors.