# Read integers from file - line by line

Tags: c++

How can I read integers from a file to the array of integers in c++? So that, for example, this file's content:

```
23
31
41
23
```

would become:

```
int *arr = {23, 31, 41, 23};
```

?

I actually have two problems with this. First is that I don't really know how can I read them line by line. For one integer it would be pretty easy, just `file_handler >> number` syntax would do the thing. How can I do this line by line?

The second problem which seems more difficult to overcome for me is - how should I allocate the memory for this thing? :U

Comment: Use std::vector instead of the array and push_back new integers, the vector will grow allocating memory automatically

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
std::ifstream file_handler(file_name);

// use a std::vector to store your items.  It handles memory allocation automatically.
std::vector<int> arr;
int number;

while (file_handler>>number) {
  arr.push_back(number);

  // ignore anything else on the line
  file_handler.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
}
```

Comment: Uhh, vectors...I'd have to pass this one by parameter to the other function - is this o.k.? I've heard it's pretty slow.

Comment: @user2252786: if you pass a reference it isn't slow.  And it probably isn't that slow anyway.

Comment: @user2252786: It's not slow. Don't listen to everything you hear (except it's here on SO).

Comment: @user2252786: Vectors are just as fast as arrays. http://stackoverflow.com/q/3664272/14065

Comment: Doing `for(int number; file_handler>>number;)` is cleaner than using while IMO

Answer (score 2):

don't use array use vector.

```
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <fstream>

int main()
{
    std::ifstream      file("FileName");
    std::vector<int>   arr(std::istream_iterator<int>(file), 
                           (std::istream_iterator<int>()));
                       // ^^^ Note extra paren needed here.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just use `file >> number` for this. It just knows what to do with spaces and linebreaks.

For variable-length array, consider using `std::vector`.

This code will populate a vector with all numbers from a file.

```
int number;
vector<int> numbers;
while (file >> number)
    numbers.push_back(number);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to do it:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>

int main()
{
    std::ifstream file("c:\\temp\\testinput.txt");
    std::vector<int> list;

    std::istream_iterator<int> eos, it(file);

    std::copy(it, eos, std::back_inserter(list));

    std::for_each(std::begin(list), std::end(list), [](int i)
    {
        std::cout << "val: " << i << "\n";
    });
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can use std::copy to print as well: `std::copy(list.begin(), list.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, "\n"));`

Comment: Yes but I'm limited to a delimiter and for the clarity of the output I wanted to put the "val:" prefix.