# C/C++ fill struct array with one value

Tags: c++, c, memory, struct, memcpy

I'd like to fill array of MyStruct with same value. How can it be done in fastest and simplest way? I'm operating on rather low-level methods, like `memset` or `memcpy`.

edit: `std::fill_n` indeed complies and works fine. But it's C++ way. **How can it be done in pure C?**

```
struct MyStruct
{
    int a;
    int b;
};

void foo()
{
    MyStruct abc;
    abc.a = 123;
    abc.b = 321;

    MyStruct arr[100];
    // fill 100 MyStruct's with copy of abc
    std::fill_n(arr, 100, abc); // working C++ way

    // or maybe loop of memcpy? But is it efficient?
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        memcpy(arr[i],abc,sizeof(MyStruct));
}
```

Comment: What error did you get with `std::fill_n`?

Comment: `std::fill_n(arr, 100, abc);` [compiles](http://ideone.com/1LBfQz)

Comment: When you post a question like this to SO you'll get to a useful answer fastest, if not solve the problem yourself, but posting a working [sscce](http://sscce.org/) and all relevant output - in this case posting the compiler error would probably have revealed the problem was that you didn't `#include <algorithm>`.

For your sscce, use something like ideone.com to put together an example independent of your build system.

Comment: @P0W : it compiles indeed. My bad. I've modified question.

Comment: You can only get opinions on the fastest way for this (As there are a whole bunch of things we do not know from the question). The only way to find the fastest is to try them and time it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Be careful to type names of your types correctly (it's case sensitive) and don't forget the semicolon after the definition of your `struct`, apart from these, your program should compile with no problems:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

struct MyStruct
{
    int a;
    int b;
}; // <------------- HERE

int main() {
    MyStruct abc;
    abc.a = 123;
    abc.b = 321;

    MyStruct arr[100];
    std::fill_n(arr, 100, abc);

    std::cout << arr[99].b;
}
```

outputs `321`.

---

*"How can it be done in fastest and simplest way?"*

The simplest way would probably be using `std::vector` and its appropriate constructor instead:

```
#include <vector>

void foo()
{
    MyStruct abc;
    abc.a = 123;
    abc.b = 321;

    std::vector<MyStruct> vec(100, abc);
    ...
}
```

Comment: _Simplest_ but not sure if its _fastest_ ?

Comment: @P0W: Fair enough. Edited.

Comment: @POW: I bet it is: [std::vector is so much slower than plain arrays?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3664349/14065). Ps vector is not slower. Personally I would not even declare the extra variable `abc`. Either add a constructor so you can use like this: `std::vector<MyStruct> vec(100, MyStruct(123,321));` or use C++11 initializer list `std::vector<MyStruct> vec(100, {123,321});`

Comment: It's working fine, thanks! My problem is solved, but question is still open - is there a pure C way of doing that?

Comment: @gogowitczak: Unfortunately I don't know C its a completely different language.

Answer (score 2):

```
for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    arr[i] = abc;
}
```

Fastest and cleanest. The optimizer will most likely work it's magic too.

Answer (score 2):

The following should work in C

```
MyStruct arr[100] = {
   {123,321},{123,321},{123,321},{123,321},{123,321},{123,321},{123,321},{123,321},{123,321},{123,321},
   {123,321},{123,321},{123,321},{123,321},{123,321},{123,321},{123,321},{123,321},{123,321},{123,321},
   {123,321},{123,321},{123,321},{123,321},{123,321},{123,321},{123,321},{123,321},{123,321},{123,321},
   {123,321},{123,321},{123,321},{123,321},{123,321},{123,321},{123,321},{123,321},{123,321},{123,321},
   {123,321},{123,321},{123,321},{123,321},{123,321},{123,321},{123,321},{123,321},{123,321},{123,321},
   {123,321},{123,321},{123,321},{123,321},{123,321},{123,321},{123,321},{123,321},{123,321},{123,321},
   {123,321},{123,321},{123,321},{123,321},{123,321},{123,321},{123,321},{123,321},{123,321},{123,321},
   {123,321},{123,321},{123,321},{123,321},{123,321},{123,321},{123,321},{123,321},{123,321},{123,321},
   {123,321},{123,321},{123,321},{123,321},{123,321},{123,321},{123,321},{123,321},{123,321},{123,321},
   {123,321},{123,321},{123,321},{123,321},{123,321},{123,321},{123,321},{123,321},{123,321},{123,321}};
```

Comment: Downvote from me. That works only when initializing array and it's stupid way.

Comment: @gogowitczak: You don;t have anything else in C.

Comment: Yes I do, look at other answers.

Comment: @gogowitczak: I was referring to you only have arrays in C. There are no other container structures. You can fill an array with 0 (using memcpy (That is the only value guaranteed to work for an array with a structure like that)). Use a loop to fill it. Or use an initializer list. Those are your **ONLY** options in 'C'.

Comment: voting up, it is still an option, and I was looking for this one.

Answer (score 0):

Not pure C, but GCC allows you to do it quite nicely:

```
MyStruct arr[100] = { [ 0 ... 99 ] = { .a = 123, .b = 321 } };
```

If you need pure C, I'd [follow Tri-Edge Al's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19481450/1111371).

Comment: Again, it's only for initializing. I need to set whole table without reallocating memory.

Answer (score 0):

My guess in the C99 would be below code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct MyStruct
{
    int a ;
    int b ;
} MyStruct_t;

const MyStruct_t abc = 
{
    .a = 0,
    .b = 321, 
};

void main(void)
{
    int i = 0 ;

    MyStruct_t arr[100] = {0} ;

    for(i=0 ;i <sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);i++)
    {
        arr[i] = abc ;
    }
}
```

In my opinion this is cleanest, safest solution.

Answer (score 0):

here is how i did it in c:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

struct MyStruct{
    int a;
    int b;
};

/*fill the array with a specified element.*/
void fillArray(void* array, int arraySize, void* elem, int elemSize){
    for(int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++){
        memcpy((char*)array + i * elemSize, elem, elemSize);
    }
}

int main(){
    struct MyStruct array[10];
    struct MyStruct elem;
    elem.a = 123;
    elem.b = 321;
    fillArray(array, 10, &elem, sizeof(struct MyStruct));
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        printf("%i, %i\n", array[i].a, array[i].b);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I create a function called `fillArray` which uses `memcpy` to copy a specified element into each slot of the array. I now just put the corresponding element into the function parameter and print it out.