# Deleteing 2D array correctly?

Tags: c++, arrays, memory, memory-management

My question arises from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19485992/982049) answer.
In the comments he mentions that I should delete the allocated dynamic 2D array in the reverse order.
However I did not understand much why this should be done. Here is the code:

```
//intialising array
int size = 10000;
double **array = new double[size];
for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    array[i] = new double[size];

//conventional de-initialise
for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    delete[] array[i];
delete[] array;

//reverse de-initialise
for(int i = size - 1; size >= 0; i--)//notice reverse order here
    delete[] array[i];
delete[] array;
```

So my question is, is there any significant difference between the 2 methods of de-allocating a 2D array?

Comment: The C++ convention is to destruct objects in the reverse of the order the objects were constructed. But, this convention has little relevance to dynamically allocated objects, except where the objects depend on each other.

Comment: No (but you really shouldn't do either one).

Comment: @Jerry could you please tell me why you said that I shouldnt do either?

Comment: The difference between these methods is simply the order in which memory will be deallocated. The result will be the same in both cases.

Comment: @Cool_Coder: Because what you usually want to do is use a 1D array (or a `std::vector`), then overload `operator()` to take two operands, and convert from row/column to a linear index into that array/vector.

Comment: @Jerry vector is completely out of focus if the requirement is heavy number crunching. Arrays are better at this IMHO.
Now what is the advantage of using a 1D array? Would not it be difficult to obtain say 1000000 contigous blocks of 8 bytes rather than using 1000 different blocks (each having 1000 blocks of 8 bytes)? The effect of cache is not much significant here I believe. What do you say?

Comment: @Cool_Coder: My experience is that vector vs. array has no measurable effect on serious number crunching, and an array of pointers to arrays will be slower than either. The effect of caching can be quite significant here. The row arrays are non-contiguous, *and* you need to devote cache space to the array of pointers, but reducing its effectiveness.

Comment: I'm going to have nightmares of pointers. Use `vector` :(

Comment: http://ideone.com/1wbFeJ Also note how your code is not exception safe at all and when you look at how the identical `vector` solution looks you can see your performance worries are misguided because the data is not contiguous.

Comment: In the case of an array the data is contiguous so definitely the cache performance will definitely be the best. I do not know whether vector stores data in contiguous memory or not. If it doesnt then for sure its performance is going to be bad than 2D array. Now for 1D array there MIGHT be a small performance improvement compared to 2D array, but I feel allocating 8 * 1000 * 1000 bytes of contiguous memory would be rather instable compared to having a 1000 blocks (each of 8 * 1000 bytes) at independent locations would be much stable.

Comment: `std::vector`s are contiguous; the point I was making is that you have an array of *pointers* to arrays. While the contents of each array is contiguous, the arrays themselves are not contiguous with each other, just like in the `vector` example. They are identical in performance.

Answer (score 0):

In your example there's no difference - you create 100K pointers, and then allocate memory for each. It doesn't matter how you allocate/deallocate memory and assign it to pointers array.

However your question is about why reverse deallocation was in another post, and opposite to your example it matters - counter variable is reused to countdown from last allocated object down to 0, when new memory allocation failed. If deallocating other direction you'd need additional variable there:

```
try
{
    array = new double*[size];

    // Don't shadow counter here.
    for(counter = 0; counter < size; counter++)
    {
        array[counter] = new double[size];
    }
}
catch(std::bad_alloc)
{
    // delete in reverse order to mimic other containers.
    for(--counter; counter >= 0;--counter)
    {
        delete[] array[counter];
    }

    delete[] array;
```