# What data structure to use to store text file quickly, which has variable no. of lines and variable no. of sub elements quickly, in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, performance, data-structures, vector

The first priority is performance (**speed**) in ms.
**What data structure to use to store text file quickly?**
**Given** that the text file could have variable no. of lines.
Each line have variable no. of co-ordinates. And each of those co-ordinates need to go through calculations.
**Also**, I want to sequentially access points, to do the calculations. And remove some of the co-ordinates, if necessary.
There will be enough memory space available, thousand time more than the file size.

```
x1,y1 x2,y2 ....
x6,y6 x7,y7 .....
......
```

To be precise, the file is as below-

```
7866.777,505.821 -7866.773,508.291 -786.8402,500.845 -7864835.125147422,5084020.882938482
-7865228.42,508.491642 -7864114.999361482,5081606.040795522
-8865228.42,508.4642 -7864.999361,5081.040795522
```

Now how do I store each element quickly? 
Can I store it in vector? It is flexible, but its slow.
Can I store it in 2d array? Is it fastest? But it has variable number of lines and different number of elements in each line. Also, number of elements in array needs to be constant, so is there other way to use dynamically growing array?

**Update**
Since, details were asked, I'm updating the questions with details and trying to be precise as possible.

Comment: _'Can I store it in vector? It is flexible, but its slow.'_ How did you measure this?

Comment: What you should really do first, is to profile and measure your program, to see where the actual bottlenecks are. Also, do you *really need* it to be faster? What are your requirements? What are your use-cases? What *are you doing*? Please read about [the XY problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: For any sane situation, most of the time is spent on text-formatting, not storing the data. If you really need to significantly boost performance, use binary serialize representation and skip formatting.

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ - In this case, we don't know number of lines and sub elements ahead in time. So, I'm using vector with pushback. But, I read pushback is expensive than array. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3664272/stdvector-is-so-much-slower-than-plain-arrays

Comment: @Joachim - Speed is requirement beside correctness, that's why I mentioned it in the question.

Comment: _'But, I read pushback is expensive'_ depends on initial/subsequent alloc size. Also you don't need the line numbers, if it's all integer data in the file you're well off with `while(instream >> number) { datavec.push_back(number); }` IMHO (there are various methods to just skip the `','` characters).

Comment: You are going to need to be more precise on your requirements. What operations do you need (exhaustively) ? What kind of measurements are you looking at (memory, time) ? *fast*, *expensive*, etc... mean nothing, `< 1ms` or `O(1)` is meaningful.

Comment: @MatthieuM. I have updated the question. I have to do spatial operations in those co-ordinates. The main concern is to improve the time, since enough memory is provided.

Answer (score 4):

"Store it quickly" doesn't make sense.
The fastest way to literally *store* the data in memory is a plain string/vector.
If you need to *retrieve* the data is *also* to read it from a plain string/vector.
The fastest way to *manipulate* the data in-place is probably to use a data structure called a "rope", but that's not part of the C++ standard library, so you'll have to find it elsewhere.

At the moment I feel like you're unclear on what you actually want to do, though, so it's hard to give an accurate answer.

Answer (score 2):

One way could be to read the whole file into a [`std::istringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istringstream), then use that instead of the file. Using `std::istringstream` means that the whole file will be in memory which is much faster than a disk.

Comment: Did you really just recommend using I/O streams to a question about high-performance data structures?!

Comment: @Mehrdad At least it's a way to get into memory. The main question is, I think, do the OP really *need* to have the arcane, cryptic and unreadable (and therefore hard to maintain) code that comes from the most optimized low-level stuff that's needed to shave of a couple of milliseconds?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg How can I use istringstream to read/stores values in the above case? Do you have any example or reference link.