# C++, bad performance when instantiating a std::vector

Tags: c++, arrays, performance, vector, stl

I have a question regarding the instantiation of std::vector. I compare instantiation of an std::vector and a dynamic allocation of an array of  the same size. I was expecting that the instantiation of the std::vector would take a little bit longer but I have a huge difference performance.

For the array I have 53 us
For the std::vector I have 4338 us

my code:

```
#include <chrono>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    unsigned int NbItem = 1000000 ;
    std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock> start, middle ,end;
    start = std::chrono::system_clock::now() ;
    float * aMallocArea = (float *)calloc(sizeof(float)*NbItem,0) ;
    middle = std::chrono::system_clock::now() ;
    std::vector<float> aNewArea ;
    middle = std::chrono::system_clock::now() ;
    aNewArea.resize(NbItem) ;
    //float * aMallocArea2 = new float[NbItem];
    end = std::chrono::system_clock::now() ;
    std::chrono::duration<double> elapsed_middle = middle-start;
    std::chrono::duration<double> elapsed_end = end-middle;
    std::cout << "ElapsedTime CPU  = " << elapsed_middle.count()*1000000 << " (us) " << std::endl ;
    std::cout << "ElapsedTime CPU  = " << elapsed_end.count()*1000000 << " (us) " << std::endl ;
    free(aMallocArea) ;
    return 0;
}
```

Even if I create a vector of size 0 I have this difference. 
Do you know why I have such bad performance when I am instantiating a std::vector ?
Do you know how to improve this  (I tried to use compilation option -O3 but it does not give outstanding result).

Compilation line:
g++ --std=c++11 -o test  ./src/test.cpp

compilator version:
g++ --version
g++ (Debian 4.7.2-5) 4.7.2
Copyright (C) 2012 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

Comment: The first time instantiation of `std::vector` may incur overhead. But what about subsequent instantiations?

Comment: Please provide your compipler version and compilation command line.

Comment: `calloc(sizeof(float)*NbItem,0)` This is a bit weird, allocating 0 size objects. Not that it is the issue, but I would try allocating at least of size 1 and see if it behaves any differently.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3664272/stdvector-is-so-much-slower-than-plain-arrays?rq=1

Comment: Passing a size of 0 to `calloc` is implementation defined and makes the whole comparison completely worthless since it might just return `Null` without doing any allocation. See: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/c/calloc

Comment: @clam37 `calloc` actually seems to be the slowest, and `new` the fastest, with `vector.reserve()` being a bit of a cheating in my own tests: [using clang](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0dbe7e797920fe06), [using gcc](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6cc1b85cd639d268). Algorithms are only used to prevent the compiler from optimizing out the whole thing.

Comment: The time taken by the allocation function is only the tip of the iceberg. [This article](http://randomascii.wordpress.com/2014/12/10/hidden-costs-of-memory-allocation/) has a good discussion of some of the other factors.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do you realize that this:

```
float * aMallocArea = (float *)calloc(sizeof(float)*NbItem, 0);
```

means "Allocate `sizeof(float)*NbItem` items which have the size of zero"? This means that the call performs an allocation of zero bytes.

Even once you do correct this, the `calloc` form will be much faster in many cases. `calloc` implementations are capable of "reserving" a memory domain and returning a pointer. When you *access* the memory, the OS maps the virtual memory.

A vector on the other hand, actually goes through and initializes/constructs its elements. No implementation I know of checks to see that a) the type is POD, b) memory is zero, and c) that the allocator returns zeroed memory. So this initialization process can cost quite a bit, compared to `calloc`.

So the "C" version does next to nothing (if you fix your program), and the "C++" version goes through, initializes every element, and touches all the memory in the allocation. It will be much slower.

That is very rarely a good reason to favor the C version, even where performance matters. In practice, you should only allocate memory you actually need. Once you start *using* the memory for something, the times will even out (e.g. in the C version, it will take time to map the memory when you access it later on). If you *were* to create a second timed test which (say) computed the average of the arrays' elements, the C++ version would likely be faster on your implementation because the memory is already mapped and initialized, whereas the C version would perform mapping and initialization as you read the memory.

Comment: For more information on the overhead when the memory is actually touched (especially when it is written):
http://randomascii.wordpress.com/2014/12/10/hidden-costs-of-memory-allocation/

Comment: Thank you for helping me to understand my issue. I will try to implement the test you have suggested.