# C++ Theta function implementation

Tags: c++

I am trying to implement this function:

> [image: formula]

but it's not working. A minimal, verifiable example looks like:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

int main()
{
  int N {8};        // change this for testing <1..inf>
  double q {0.1 / N};
  int countN {static_cast<int>(floor(N / 2))};
  static const double PI {3.1415926535897932384626433832795};

  // Omega[i] =  Theta1(u,m) / Theta4(u,m)
  double Omega[countN];
  for (int i=0; i<countN; ++i)
  {
    double micro {!(N % 2) * 0.5};  // 0 for odd N, 1/2 for even N
    double num[countN] {sin(PI / N * (i + 1 - micro))};
    double den[countN] {0.5};

    for (int m=1; m<4; ++m)
    {
        num[i] += pow(-1, m) * pow(q, m*(m + 1)) * sin((2 * m + 1) * PI / N * (i + 1 - micro));
        den[i] += pow(-1, m) * pow(q, m*m) * cos(2 * m * PI / N * (i + 1 - micro));

    }
    Omega[i] = fabs(pow(q, 0.25) * num[i] / den[i]);
    std::cout << "  " << Omega[i] << "\n";
  }

  // testing the values, they should be increasing in value
  for (const auto &elem: Omega)
    std::cout << elem << " ";
  std::cout << "\n";

  return 0;
}
```

There is a minor simplification compared to the original: I factored 2 in both numerator and denominator and I used only the `q^0.25` outside of the fraction. Also, `countN` is the `r` from the original document, `micro` is only the `1/2` for even `N` or `0` for odd `N`, and `i` is 0 for array's index but `i+1` for calculations, but these shouldn't matter overall.

I tried this with wxMaxima:

```
Theta[1](x,y):=2*y^0.25*sum( (-1)^k*y^(k*(k+1))*sin((2*k+1)*x),k,0,n );
Theta[4](x,y):=1+2*sum( (-1)^k*y^(k^2)*cos(2*k*x),k,1,n );
n:4$
N:8$
a:0.05$
b(i):=%pi/N*(i-(1-mod(N,2))/2)$
for N:8 thru 9 do for i:1 thru N/2 do print(["N=",N,"i=",i],Theta[1](b(i),a)/Theta[4](b(i),a)),numer;
```

And the results, in C++:

```
(q=0.05; N=8)
Omega[0]=0.2018370065366672
Omega[1]=0.06058232646142273
Omega[2]=0.01205653570636574
Omega[3]=0.02127667733703158
(q=0.05; N=9)
Omega[0]=0.348078726440638
Omega[1]=0.1178366281313341
Omega[2]=2.559808325080287e-07
Omega[3]=0.02178788541277828
```

and in wxMaxima:

```
["N=",8,"i=",1]" "0.2018370065366672" "
["N=",8,"i=",2]" "0.5439269564954693" "
["N=",8,"i=",3]" "0.7569342043740249" "
["N=",8,"i=",4]" "0.850913653939989" "
["N=",9,"i=",1]" "0.348078726440638" "
["N=",9,"i=",2]" "0.6165773889432575" "
["N=",9,"i=",3]" "0.7800391631077094" "
["N=",9,"i=",4]" "0.8532352152763631
```

To my surprise, the first term is good, for bith `N`, so I can't tell what in my code is not right. Could someone help me spot the error?

To be clear about it: I am a beginner in C++ and I am not looking for someone to do it for me, but to let me know of my erros in coding (translating math to C++ code).

Comment: I won't claim that this is the "best" of questions, but if it's going to be down-voted, at least let me know why so I can correct it. What I want is not for someone else to do it for me, but to let me know my error in implementation. I should have added I am a beginner in C++.

Comment: I didn't vote, but if you're going to show us code, then show only the code that you intend us to look at, not code that includes lines that should be *ignored*.

Comment: There are only two std::cout lines in there and they only print out the temporary steps, I didn't think they would get in the way. But I'll delete the lines, I'm sorry for the confusion.

Comment: the problem statement should be in the question, not referenced in a slide of a pdf somewhere.

Comment: I recommend using temporary variables, and splitting that monster of a statement to multiple trivial statements (goes for both numerator and denumerator) to more easily verify correctness.

Comment: I split the inner for loop to have one `for(m=0..N)` for `num` and one `for(1..N)` for `den`, while leaving the initial variables uninitialized (0), and now it works! I don't understand, because (in the same pdf) there is also a `sinh/cosh` version and that one is implemented like in the OP, and it works! Only, that one is static, not a function of `[i]`. Well, the good news it works, now that I split it, thank you for the guides. Do you think `for(m) { a=...; b=...; }` is the same as `for(m) { a=...; }` and `for(n) { b=...; }` ?

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen `double den[countN] {0.5};` means `double den[countN] {0.5,0.0,0.0,0.0};`, not that `num` or `den` need to be arrays if you're going to just use one value

Comment: Your code doesn't have a `main()`, so nobody can compile and compare results.  You should [edit] your question to give it a [mcve].

Comment: @PeterT Ah! I knew the initialization was like that, but I forgot to count it for greater `i`! which means the first term is right, but the rest have a `0.5` less, each! That's my mistake! Thank you! This will not be a lesson easily forgotten.

Comment: @TobySpeight I'm sorry for the lack of a complete code. Now that I know my error, rather than edit a 4th time, could this be marked as solved? PeterT is the one that spotted the error.

Comment: @TobySpeight I modified it, but it's as good as solved now. Thank you all that helped.

Comment: I turned the comment by @Peter into an answer; accept it if it solves your problem.  Note that you shouldn't change the erroneous code in your question, as that means the answer no longer directly addresses it - I'll change that back for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had

```
double den[countN] {0.5};
```

this initializes the first element of `den` to `0.5` *and all the other elements to `0.0`* (default initialization).  In other words, the above is equivalent to

```
double den[countN] {0.5, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0};
```

with as many zeros as necessary to fill the array.  You probably wanted to initialize all the elements to `0.5`.  In your case, the easiest way to do that is when you first use that element - or, since you access only the single element `den[i]` during the lifetime of `den`, make it a plain `double` rather than an array:

```
for (int i=0; i<countN; ++i) {
    double micro {N % 2 ? 0.0 : 0.5};  // 0 for odd N, 1/2 for even N
    double num{sin(PI / N * (i + 1 - micro))};
    double den{0.5};

    for (int m=1; m<4; ++m) {
        num += pow(-1, m) * pow(q, m*(m + 1)) * sin((2 * m + 1) * PI / N * (i + 1 - micro));
        den += pow(-1, m) * pow(q, m*m) * cos(2 * m * PI / N * (i + 1 - micro));
    }
    Omega[i] = fabs(pow(q, 0.25) * num / den);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution (and sorry for the mix up). It didn't occur to me that `num` and `den` are only local to `for(m)`, maybe because I had initialized them before. At any rate, there is also a `&sigma;<sub>0</sub>` which uses the same sums but with `sinh/cosh`, and with `&Lambda;` instead of `PI/N*(i+1-&micro;)`, and there I had used fixed values (non-array), exactly the way you show up in there. But, my bad reasoning was that I should use an array since `&Omega;<sub>i</sub>` is a function of `i`. Marked as solved.

Comment: Still, with this occasion, I also found out I can initialize a vector like this: `std::vector<double> matrix(nrOfTimes, value)`. If I use `std::vector` as a fixed array, non-dynamically resized, is there a speed penalty?

Comment: That's a question of its own - see if it's already been answered here on StackOverflow, and if you can't find an answer, then please ask it as a new question.  You're almost certainly not the only person interested to know!

Comment: You're right, in fact, here's my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3664272/is-stdvector-so-much-slower-than-plain-arrays