# std::vector accesses memory almost twice as many times as raw pointer does - why?

Tags: c++

I have a rather basic question about the memory behavior of std::vector. I would like to understand why a simple loop through a vector is much slower than the same loop using a raw pointer.

This is code0:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include "utils.h" //contains Timer
using namespace std;

void ff(double * p, int n) {

  for (int i =0; i< n ; i++) p[i]+=i;

}

int main() {
  int n = 1e9;
  Timer t;  //comes from "utils.h"
  t.tic();     //start timer
  double * p = new double[n];
  ff(p, n);
  delete[] p;
  double tt = t.toc();     //stop timer
  cout << tt << endl;     // number of seconds recorded by t.
}
```

When I compile and run code0 I get the following output: 3.88309.

This is codeV:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include "utils.h"
using namespace std;

void ff(vector<double>& v, int n) {

  for (int i =0; i< n ; i++) v[i]+=i;

}

int main() {
  int n=1e9;
  Timer t;
  t.tic();
  vector<double> v(n);
  ff(v, n);
  double tt = t.toc();
  cout << tt << endl; 
}
```

When I compile and run codeV I get the following output: 5.25866.

As you can see, code0 and codeV are doing the same thing, but the first is implemented with pointer and the second with std::vector.
However codeV is almost twice as slow as code0.

Let me remark that I compiled both codes without optimization flags and using g++.

Out of curiosity I ran valgrind and perf on code0 and codeV, and it turns out that:

1) codeV performs 455,378,126 cache references, while code0 only 185,640,714;

2) codeV has about 50% cache misses among its memory calls, while code0 less than 5%.

If compiled with optimization flags on, the difference in time become less marked, though those on memory are still noticeable. I would like to ask: what is going on ? Why is std::vector performing so much worse than a raw pointer on such a simple task?

Thank you for any insight on this issue!

Comment: Your code uses `std::vector` but your text says `std::array` - which is it?

Comment: Perhaps look at the generated assembly for `ff`.

Comment: Your code isn't equivalent. To make it so, change it to `new double[n]();`. In fact, your first code has undefined behaviour because it reads an uninitialized value.

Comment: You got undefined behavior by reading uninitialized values in your first code snippet. The vector version is properly initializing each double to `0`

Comment: `Let me remark that I compiled both codes without optimization flags` Which really makes your comparison invalid. Does your vector implementation have iterator and bounds checking in a debug build?

Comment: Indeed, a comparison without optimization is not a fair one. Many implementation has debug checks and abstraction are not inlined out in debug builds.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is std::vector so much slower than plain arrays?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3664272/is-stdvector-so-much-slower-than-plain-arrays)

Comment: Why did you concentrate on performance instead of the output being different?   If you see different output, investigate that first.

Comment: Thanks for your comments.I mean vector and edited accordingly. Also using new double[]() the 'vector' version is slower than 'pointer' one. Unfortunately I can't answer your questions about bound-debug checking because I don't know what it is... in terminal I run: g++ -std=c++11 codeV.cpp -o codeV.out && ./codeV.out

Comment: Could bound checking be the reason why there are so many memory calls?

Comment: *in terminal I run: g++ -std=c++11 codeV.cpp -o codeV.o* -- This is meaningless without optimizations turned on.  See the answer.

Comment: If you [inspect](https://godbolt.org/z/zvipdX) the generated assembly with `-O3 -DNDEBUG` in godbolt (I inlined the call to avoid introducing template magic), well it looks like identical, so I guess something is wrong in your methodology.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without optimization, all of the C++ standard library will be slower than C code. Without optimization, all of C is slower than hand-written assembly. What do you expect?

In order to use `std::vector` without optimization, the compiler has to write out about four function calls for each write to a vector element, compared to the single array write in C.

Use at least `-O2`. `-O3 -DNDEBUG` is my preference. Use `-flto` and `-fprofile-generate` / `-fprofile-use` too. Look them up.

If you aren't writing C++ to be fast, why use it at all?

Comment: Will look them up and play with them. Thank you!