# vector reserve + emplace_back slower than plain array

Tags: c++, arrays, performance, optimization, vector

I'm aware that vectors with resize or/and push_back are slower than plain arrays due to additional creations/copies of objects. [Most](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3664272/is-stdvector-so-much-slower-than-plain-arrays) questions asked before about slowness of vectors are about resize/push_back slowness. Usual advice is to use reserve+emplace_back because they're faster than push_back.

I've done some benchmarks according to whiches reserve+emplace_back are much slower than plain arrays. Why? Am I missing something that makes comparison unfair?

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <vector>
#include <chrono>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <climits>
using tp = std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point;
class Time {
public:
    static void show(tp t1, tp t2) { //time passed since t1
        std::cout << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(t2 - t1).count() << '\t';
        printf("nanoseconds \n");
    }
    tp add() {
        tp p = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
        return p;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Time time;
    const int VSIZE = 1000000;
    auto t1 = time.add();
    double vsizearr[VSIZE];
    for (auto i = 0; i < VSIZE; i++) {
        vsizearr[i]=i;
        asm volatile("" : : : "memory"); //doesn't allow compiler to erase the loop
    }
    auto t2 = time.add();
    std::vector<double> second;
    second.reserve(VSIZE);
    for (auto i = 0; i < VSIZE; i++) {
        second.emplace_back(i);
        asm volatile("" : : : "memory"); //doesn't allow compiler to erase the loop
    }
    auto t3 = time.add();
    time.show(t1, t2);
    time.show(t2, t3);
    return 0;
}
```

Benchmarks results:

Windows 10, C++17, LLVM-clang, -O1

```
306300  nanoseconds
1824700 nanoseconds
```

Ubuntu 20.04, C++17, g++ and clang

```
root@vlad-VirtualBox:/home/vlad/Documents clang++ -O1 -std=c++17 -o test test.cpp
root@vlad-VirtualBox:/home/vlad/Documents ./test
284340 nanoseconds 
3115997 nanoseconds 
root@vlad-VirtualBox:/home/vlad/Documents g++ -O1 -std=c++17 -o test test.cpp
root@vlad-VirtualBox:/home/vlad/Documents ./test
284340 nanoseconds 
3145702 nanoseconds
```

-O3 results are about the same as -O1.

Comment: In your 1st version the array is on the stack. In the 2nd, the `std::vector` is allocating on the heap. Use `new[]` + `delete[]` in the 1st version for a fair comparison.

Comment: vsizearr accesses are entirely optimised out as the compiler sees it been set but not used ever.

Comment: Thanks, stack/heap difference answers my question.

Answer (score 3):

**The benchmark is biased**: it does not measure what you think. Indeed, both GCC 12.2 and Clang 15.0 optimize the first loop so **nothing is actually written**. See this on [GodBolt](https://godbolt.org/z/1P8vKaYcx).

Here is the code for the first loop with GCC and Clang:

```
; [GCC]
        mov     eax, 1000000
.L31:
        sub     eax, 1
        jne     .L31

------------------------------

; [Clang]
        mov     ebx, 1000000
.LBB0_1:
        dec     ebx
        jne     .LBB0_1
```

As you can see, the loop is empty and useless, so it is not surprising it is fast. The compiler optimize it since the *array is not read*.

For the second loop, here is the assembly code of the loop:

```
; [GCC]
.L43:
        pxor    xmm0, xmm0
        cvtsi2sd        xmm0, eax
        movsd   QWORD PTR [rsi], xmm0
        add     rsi, 8
        mov     QWORD PTR [rsp+24], rsi
.L33:
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rsp+12]
        add     eax, 1
        mov     DWORD PTR [rsp+12], eax
        cmp     eax, 999999
        jg      .L42
.L34:
        mov     rsi, QWORD PTR [rsp+24]
        cmp     rsi, QWORD PTR [rsp+32]
        jne     .L43
        lea     rdx, [rsp+12]
        lea     rdi, [rsp+16]
        call    void std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> >::_M_realloc_insert<int&>(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<double*, std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> > >, int&)
        jmp     .L33

------------------------------

; [Clang]
.LBB0_5:                                #   in Loop: Header=BB0_4 Depth=1
        xorps   xmm0, xmm0
        cvtsi2sd        xmm0, r15d
        movsd   qword ptr [rbx], xmm0
.LBB0_32:                               #   in Loop: Header=BB0_4 Depth=1
        add     rbx, 8
        inc     r15d
        cmp     r15d, 1000000
        je      .LBB0_6
.LBB0_4:                                # =>This Inner Loop Header: Depth=1
        cmp     rbx, rcx
        jne     .LBB0_5
[...]
```

As you can see, GCC does not optimize the call to `_M_realloc_insert`. Both keep the array writes, not to mention the expensive int-to-double conversion. There is an expensive logic so to know whether the array need to be resized. This is needed since **the compiler can hardly know this part is actually not useful**.

Comment: Thanks. I thought asm volatile always helps to prevent too-much optimization. I was wrong.