# Overhead to using std::vector?

Tags: c++, stdvector, dynamic-memory-allocation

I know that manual dynamic memory allocation is a bad idea in general, but is it sometimes a better solution than using, say, `std::vector`?

To give a crude example, if I had to store an array of `n` integers, where `n` <= 16, say. I could implement it using

```
int* data = new int[n]; //assuming n is set beforehand
```

or using a vector:

```
std::vector<int> data;
```

Is it absolutely always a better idea to use a `std::vector` or could there be practical situations where manually allocating the dynamic memory would be a better idea, to increase efficiency?

Comment: You don't have to `push_back`. `std::vector<int>(n)` is *almost* equivalent to your dynamic array version, except that the `n` integers are value, hence zero, initialized in the vector.

Comment: @juanchopanza: Fair point. I removed the `push_back` part. It wasn't supposed to be part of the comparision.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It is always better to use `std::vector`/`std::array`, at least until you can *conclusively prove* (through profiling) that the `T* a = new T[100];` solution is considerably faster in your specific situation. This is unlikely to happen: `vector`/`array` is an extremely thin layer around a plain old array. There is some overhead to bounds checking with `vector::at`, but you can circumvent that by using `operator[]`.

Comment: The usual reason for using C style arrays has nothing to do with speed; it's for static initialization, and for the compiler to determine the size according to the number of initializers.  (Which, of course, never applies to dynamically allocated arrays).

Comment: @James If I'm reading your comment correctly, you are objecting to the fact that I seem to be bashing C-style arrays without saying that I mean dynamically allocated ones? If so, I have edited my answer regarding this. (Also, +1 to your answer.)

Comment: That clears it up. I didn't know that `vector`/`array` is a thin layer. I kinda assumed that with all the functionality, it must have a significant overhead.

Comment: You said "It is always...until...solution is considerably faster".  I didn't read it as being restricted to dynamic allocation.  (As I said in my answer, I have _never_ used an array `new`.  Before `std::vector` and `std::string`, the first thing one did was to write something equivalent.)  But while I never use array `new`, there are cases where C style arrays are justified (some, but not all of which can be replaced by `std::array` in C++11).

Answer (score 10):

I can't think of any case where dynamically allocating a C style
vector makes sense.  (I've been working in C++ for over 25
years, and I've yet to use `new[]`.)  Usually, if I know the
size up front, I'll use something like:

```
std::vector<int> data( n );
```

to get an already sized vector, rather than using `push_back`.

Of course, if `n` is very small and is known at compile time,
I'll use `std::array` (if I have access to C++11), or even
a C style array, and just create the object on the stack, with
*no* dynamic allocation.  (Such cases seem to be rare in the
code I work on; small fixed size arrays tend to be members of
classes.  Where I do occasionally use a C style array.)

Answer (score 4):

If you know the size in advance (especially at compile time), and don't need the dynamic re-sizing abilities of `std::vector`, then using something simpler is fine.

However, that something should preferably be `std::array` if you have C++11, or something like `boost::scoped_array` otherwise.

I doubt there'll be much efficiency gain unless it significantly reduces code size or something, but it's more expressive which is worthwhile anyway.

Answer (score 4):

You should try to avoid `C`-style-arrays in `C++` whenever possible. The `STL` provides containers which usually suffice for every need. Just imagine reallocation for an array or deleting elements out of its middle. The container shields you from handling this, while you would have to take care of it for yourself, and if you haven't done this a hundred times it is quite error-prone.
An exception is of course, if you are adressing low-level-issues which might not be able to cope with `STL`-containers.

There have already been some discussion about this topic. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/381621/using-arrays-or-stdvectors-in-c-whats-the-performance-gap) on SO.

Comment: +1 for the link at the end, that should destroy once and for all the myth that accessing vector elements is somehow slow.

Answer (score 3):

> Is it absolutely always a better idea to use a std::vector or could there be practical situations where manually allocating the dynamic memory would be a better idea, to increase efficiency?

Call me a simpleton, but 99.9999...% of the times I would just use a standard container. The default choice should be `std::vector`, but also [`std::deque<>` could be a reasonable option sometimes](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/054.htm). If the size is known at compile-time, opt for `std::array<>`, which is a lightweight, safe wrapper of C-style arrays which introduces zero overhead.

Standard containers expose member functions to specify the initial reserved amount of memory, so you won't have troubles with reallocations, and you won't have to remember `delete[]`ing your array. I honestly do not see why one should use manual memory management.

Efficiency shouldn't be an issue, since you have throwing and non-throwing member functions to access the contained elements, so you have a choice whether to favor safety or performance.

Answer (score 2):

*std::vector* could be constructed with an size_type parameter that instantiate the vector with the specified number of elements and that does a single dynamic allocation (same as your array) and also you can use *reserve* to decrease the number of re-allocations over the usage time.

Answer (score 1):

In `n` is known at compile-time, then you should choose `std::array` as:

```
std::array<int, n> data; //n is compile-time constant
```

and if `n` is not known at compile-time, OR the array might grow at runtime, then go for `std::vector`:

```
std::vector<int> data(n); //n may be known at runtime
```

Or in some cases, you may also prefer `std::deque` which is faster than `std::vector` in some scenario. See these:

- [**C++ benchmark – std::vector VS std::list VS std::deque**](http://www.baptiste-wicht.com/2012/12/cpp-benchmark-vector-list-deque/)
- [**Using Vector and Deque**](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/054.htm) by Herb  Sutter

Hope that helps.

Comment: Unless you know that `n` is very, very small, you probably shouldn't declare local variables as `std::array`.  Unless there is some very specific reason for doing otherwise, I'd just use `std::vector`---if I know the size, I'll initialize the vector with the correct size.  (This also supposes that the type has a default constructor.)

Answer (score 1):

From a perspective of someone who often works with low level code with C++, std vectors are really just helper methods with a safety net for a classic C style array. The only overheads you'd experience realistically are memory allocations and safety checks for boundaries. If you're writing a program which needs performance and are going to be using vectors as a regular array I'd recommend to just use C style arrays instead of vectors. You should realistically be vetting the data that comes into the application and check the boundaries yourself to avoid checks on every memory access to the array.

It's good to see that others are checking the differences of the C ways and the C++ ways. More often than not C++ standard methods have significantly worse performance and uglier syntax than their C counterparts and is generally the reason people call C++ bloated. I think C++ focuses more on safety and making the language more like JavaScript/C# even though the language fundamentally lacks the foundation to be one.