# What is the proper way to delete an array of pointers and their objects?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, dynamic

```
ppTile = new Tile*[tileN];
    for(int x=0; x<tileN; x++)
    {
        ppTile[x] = new Tile(Tile::TileType(pCData->GetdefaultTile()),
                            ((x*2)+1) % (mapSize+(mapSize-1)),
                            ( x/ ((float)mapSize-0.5) )+1,
                            pCData->GetdefaultHeight()
                            );
    }
```

How will I delete both the array of Tile* and the Tile objects?

Edit: This is my guess:

```
Map::~Map()
{
    if(ppTile)
    {
        for(int x=0; x<mapSize*(mapSize-1); x++)
        {
            delete ppTile[x];
        }
        delete[] ppTile;
    }
}
```

Is that right?

Comment: Do you actually need pointers to `Tile`s? It sounds like a `std::vector<Tile>` would probably work.

Comment: `delete` all the `Tile` objects, one by one, then `delete[]` the array.

Comment: Oh, and make sure you're aware of the Rule of Three/Five. It will bite you if you're not and you choose not to use RAII.

Comment: What is the rule of 3/5? If it has to do with dividing integers, I am intentionally doing so for the rounding downs.

Comment: @MickaelBergeronNéron no, it's about copying/assigning objects of that type and ending up with nasty situations that arise from the default shallow copying. Again, you can find good resources here on [so].

Comment: [Relevant](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three), [relevant in C++11](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4782757/rule-of-three-becomes-rule-of-five-with-c11), [MOST RELEVANT - READ THIS](http://klmr.me/slides/modern-cpp/#1).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You iterate through the `Tile*`s and `delete` each one, and then you `delete[]` the big one.

```
for(int x=0; x<tileN; x++)
{
    delete ppTile[x];
}
delete[] ppTile;
```

A good rule of thumb is to have a `delete` for each `new` and a `delete[]` for each `new[]`.

You could avoid the hassle by just using `std::vector` of smart pointers.

**As per your edit:**

I would avoid the check `if(ppTile)`. Calling `delete` on a NULL pointer is well-defined, but the check is also prone to errors - if that pointer is `NULL` and `mapSize*(mapSize-1)` isn't `0`, you'd be hiding a logical error.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `delete[] ppTile` or am I mistaken?

Comment: While I don't find this too much of an hassle, would that still be preferable to use std::vector? If so, why? Thanks by the way.

Comment: @MickaelBergeronNéron numerous posts on why you should prefer containers. Won't reiterate the reasons here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/381621/using-arrays-or-stdvectors-in-c-whats-the-performance-gap

Comment: @MickaelBergeronNéron, Look up RAII. It's the key term for vectors, smart pointers, and everything.