# Assigning Memory to a 2-d Array

Tags: c++, arrays, memory, dynamic

I am assigning memory to 2-d array for which,i know the depth

```
int *array[size];
for(int i=0;;i++)
{
   array[i]=new int[10];
}
```

Am I doing it right?

Comment: why not just wrap it in an object that has an `at` operatior, like the one vectors have? This way you don't have to have matrix aritmetiks all over your code.

Answer (score 1):

No, you need `for(int i=0; i<size; i++)` so that the loop only execute `size` times. But this is not the most elegant way to do this. In C++, it is recommended that we use STL `vector`s instead of arrays to avoid memory management:

```
vector<vector<int> > array;
```

See [Using arrays or std::vectors in C++, what's the performance gap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/381621/using-arrays-or-stdvectors-in-c-whats-the-performance-gap)

Comment: @user1838070, Well, you should consider switching to something that will manage the memory for you, like `std::vector`.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want a dynamic 2d array or an array of pointers to the heap on the stack?

An array of pointers to the heap on the stack carry on as you are (as the other poster suggested).

For a dynamic 2d array [How do I declare a 2d array in C++ using new?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/936687/how-do-i-declare-a-2d-array-in-c-using-new).

Answer (score 0):

You really should not implement a matrix in that way -- really. unless the dimensions change, please don't.

A nicer way would be:

```
template<typename Ty>
class  matrix {
public:
  const unsigned dim_x, dim_y;

private:
  Ty* const data;

public:
  matrix(const unsigned dim_x, const unsigned  dim_y) 
    : dim_x(dim_x), dim_y(dim_y), data(new Ty[dim_x *dim_y])
  {}

  ~matrix() {
    delete[] data;
  }

  const Ty at(unsigned i, unsigned j) const {
    return data[i + j*dim_x];
  }

  Ty& at(unsigned i, unsigned j) {
    return data[i + j*dim_x];
  }
};
```

And then just access the data with the matrix class.

I wrote a blogpost i thingy about it [here](http://highspeederlang.wordpress.com/2013/05/10/using-multidimensional-arrays-in-c/)