# 2D array as instance variable of class

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array

So if I have a class with a 2D array that I want to initialize with two parameters passed into the constructor, how would I do that, I keep running into errors because it won't let me update the two-d array at all in the constructor.

-- *Update from the comments:*

In my header file I tried both

```
int array[][]
```

and

```
int **array
```

and then in the .cpp file in the constructor I'm trying to do

```
array = new int[arg1][arg2]
```

Neither declaration of the array in the header file worked.

Comment: `I keep running into errors` - what does your code look like? What are the errors?

Comment: How is the array declared?

Comment: In my header file I tried both int array[][] and int **array and then in the .cpp file in the constructor I'm trying to do array = new int[arg1][arg2]. Neither declaration of the array in the header file worked.

Comment: Don't confuse a pointer to pointer with a 2D array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> in the constructor I'm trying to do array = new **array**[arg1][arg2]

You need to specify the array type, like

```
array = new int[arg1][arg2];
```

Note that [this works in C++11 only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/936687/how-do-i-declare-a-2d-array-in-c-using-new) - when using older standards, the second array size needs to be const (which is probably not what you want).

There are also some additional articles discussing the same issue:

- [Multi-Dimensional Arrays](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/articles/7459/)
- [How to "new" a two-dimension array in C++?](http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t286693-how-to-new-a-two-dimension-array-in-c.html)

Ideally, since you are using C++ anyway, you should use `std::vector` as proposed in another answer.

> Vectors use a lot of overhead though, don't they? I'm trying to keep my memory use light. –

Start with `std::vector`. Once your application is running properly from a functional perspective, if you are still concerned about memory usage and/or performance, **do benchmarking**. If you properly encapsulate your 2D array in a class, you can always change the actual implementation of the array with no impact on the code which uses it.

---

**Technically**, if you want to make sure that you have one flat memory area which contains your array, you could use a 1-dimensional array to **simulate** a 2-dimensional array, like in the following code (just to get you the idea, certainly needs some improvement, especially copy construction and assignment operators are missing):

```
class Array2D {
private:
    int *array;
    int size1;

public:
    Array2D(int arg1, int arg2) {
        size1 = arg1;
        array = new int[arg1 * arg2];
    }

    ~Array2D() {
        delete[] array;
    }

    int& at(int i1, int i2) {
        return array[i1 * size1 + i2];
    }
};

int main() {
    Array2D array(10, 10);

    array.at(2, 2) = 42;
    std::cerr << array.at(2, 2);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That's not the issue, if you look at my updated comment, I fixed that.

Comment: Then, again, what error do you get? Note that the code in my answer [works in C++11 only](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/936687/how-do-i-declare-a-2d-array-in-c-using-new) - otherwise, the second array size needs to be const

Comment: @Andreas maybe you should put your comment in the answer. It is important information (I was just writing a comment about this)

Comment: Nice solution with `Array2D`, but it needs either to implement copy construction and copy assignment, or disallow them.

Comment: Why is the line ```size1 = arg1;``` needed?

Answer (score 0):

Simplest solution would be:

```
std::vector<std::vector<VALUE>> arr2(X, std::vector<VALUE>(Y));
```

Comment: Vectors use a lot of overhead though, don't they? I'm trying to keep my memory use light.

Comment: @user1855952 I think the best solution is to use a single vector, and be clever about indices. Ideally, you could write a 2D array class using the vector as data storage.

Comment: no, they don't. Especially when the space is reserved beforehand; as is happening in above example.

Comment: @user1855952 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/381621/using-arrays-or-stdvectors-in-c-whats-the-performance-gap

Comment: Well, it depends on the use case. If the number of elements is small, a vector of vectors could have a significant size overhead over, say, a plain 2D array of contiguous elements. But one would first have to make sure this is actually an issue. The best approach is to abstract the storage away inside a 2D array class.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an 2d array example with bounds check and custom type, based upon the example from Andreas Fester.

```
#include <stdexcept>

template <typename T>
class Array2D {
private:
    T *array;
    unsigned int sizeX;
    unsigned int sizeY;

public:
    Array2D(unsigned int X, unsigned int Y) {
        sizeX = X;
        sizeY = Y;
        array = new T[X * Y];
    }

    ~Array2D() {
    delete[] array;
    }

    T& at(unsigned int X, unsigned int Y) {
        if((X > sizeX) || (Y > sizeY))
            throw std::out_of_range("Bla bla");

        return array[X * sizeX + Y];
    }
};

int main() {
    double MyValue;
    Array2D<double> *MyArray = new Array2D<double>(10, 100);
    MyArray->at(1,1) = 10.1;
    MyValue = MyArray->at(1,1);
    printf("Array value = %3.3f\n", MyValue);

    return 0;
}
```