# Vector Object Invetory, Object that can store other Object types?

Tags: c++, object, vector

I'm trying to create a Inventory system that can hold any object

for example

```
struct Ore{
    string name;
    int Size;
};

struct Wood{
    string name;
    int size;
    int color;
};
```

my idea is to create a struct with 2 vectors, one for Numeric numbers, like items with Attack, Deffense and stuff, and the other vector for Name,description or other text.
With multiple constructors for different item types.

the problem I have with it is ive heard vectors can take up more memory, and i expect this program to create hundreds or thousands of items.

So i was looking for any suggestion for bettery memory storage.

```
 struct Invetory{
 vector<float> Number;
 vector<string> Word;

   Invetory(string n,float a) 
   {Word.push_back(s); Number.push_back(a)}

   Invetory(string n,float a, float b)
   {Word.push_back(s); Number.push_back(a); Number.push_back(b);}
 };

 vector<Invetory>Bag_Space;
```

Comment: Why two vectors? Why not one vector of a class or struct objects?

Comment: " ive heard vectors can take up more memory" - malarkey

Comment: Vector is the most effective way to store data. They are dynamic unlike arrays.

Comment: That scheme only seems to make things more complicated (I'm not even sure whether it would *work*, how would you know which words and which numbers go together to form an item?) without actually having any benefits, not even for performance or memory use. That's your motivation?

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to optimize too early.

Go with whatever is the cleanest thing to use. `vector`s are not an insane choice. ([Using arrays or std::vectors in C++, what's the performance gap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/381621/using-arrays-or-stdvectors-in-c-whats-the-performance-gap))

Deal with a performance issue if/when it arises.

Checkout the following discussions on premature optimizations.

- [When is optimisation premature?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/385506/when-is-optimisation-premature)
- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/80084/is-premature-optimization-really-the-root-of-all-evil

---

BTW I stumbled upon [this interesting discussion on potential performance issues with vectors](http://lemire.me/blog/archives/2012/06/20/do-not-waste-time-with-stl-vectors/). In summary, it's saying that if your vectors are shrinking, then the memory footprint won't shrink with the vector size unless you call `swap` function.
And if you are making a lot of vectors and don't need to initialize it's elements to 0s, then instead of

```
vector<int> bigarray(N);
```

try

```
vector<int> bigarray;
bigarray.reserve(N);
```

Comment: +1 I'm sick of people that go optimization crazy before they even have a working solution, how can you possibly know its the bottleneck before it even works? Every time I profile a performance issue the bottleneck is almost always a complete surprise to me.