# How to Initialize 2D Array of QGraphicsItem

Tags: c++, arrays, qt, segmentation-fault

I'm using Qt for some gui stuff, and I have inherited QGraphicsScene to implement some of my own methods, and one of the things I did was create a list of QGraphicsItems, specifically a 2D array of an object I made which inhertits the QGraphicsItem.

```
MatrixButton **buttons;
```

Then, when I initialize the list in this method from the QGraphicsScene, I get a segmentation fault.

```
void MatrixScene::initScene()
{
    this->setSceneRect(0, 0, this->width*BUTTON_SIZE, this->height*BUTTON_SIZE);
    this->currentFrameIndex = 0;
    this->color = Qt::red;
    this->buttons = new MatrixButton*[this->height];
    for (int i = 0; i < this->height; i++){
        this->buttons[i] = new MatrixButton[this->width];
    }
    for (int x = 0; x < this->width; x++){
        for (int y = 0; y < this->height; y++){
            this->buttons[x][y].setPos(x*BUTTON_SIZE, y*BUTTON_SIZE); //SEGMENTATION FAULT!!!
            this->addItem(&this->buttons[x][y]);
        }
    }
    this->update();
}
```

When I debug the application, the debugger tells me that the problem is caused by the following line in QGraphicsItem.h:

```
inline void QGraphicsItem::setPos(qreal ax, qreal ay)
{ setPos(QPointF(ax, ay)); }
```

Specifically, the fault occurs when `ax = 640` and `ay = 0`, according to the debugger. I don't understand what would be causing the segmentation fault in this case.

Comment: 2 things: what value has this->width? second: I suggest you use `QVector<QVector<MatrixButton>>` instead of `MatrixButton**`. See here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/381621/using-arrays-or-stdvectors-in-c-whats-the-performance-gap (the same for std::vector can be applied for QVector)

Comment: @Hayt this->width is 64 for this specific test, and this->height is 32. I still would like to know out of curiosity what is causing the segmentation fault however.

Comment: What type is this->width? Floating-Point?

Comment: are you sure your loop is correct? when you check `x < this->width` X should stop at 63. Or do you have in the "real code" there `<=` ? (I assume `BUTTON_SIZE` is 10)

Comment: No, I am sure that there will never be an out of bounds error, as x increments from 0 to 63, and `BUTTON_SIZE` is 20, but that should have no effect on the outcome.

Comment: OK. you have the answer now. Note: if you would have had the `QVector()` and used .size() there instead of width etc. you would not have run into that problem ;)

Comment: I think I might switch to QVector anyways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is **you are using x as index for row and y as index for column but the boundary conditions are just opposite**

So modify your code to :

```
for (int x = 0; x < this->height; x++){
        for (int y = 0; y < this->width; y++){
            this->buttons[x][y].setPos(x*BUTTON_SIZE, y*BUTTON_SIZE);        
            this->addItem(&this->buttons[x][y]);
        }
    }
```