# c++ 2d array of class pointers

Tags: c++, arrays, class, pointers

i am trying to create a 2d array holding pointers of my class. first, i'd like to assign all of them NULL:

```
Timetable::Timetable(int hours) : TimetableBase(hours){
    scheduledLectures = new Lecture**[5];
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        scheduledLectures[i] = new Lecture*[hours];
        for (int j = 0; j < hours; j++)
            scheduledLectures[i][j] = NULL;
    };
}
```

this is for a timetable generator application. i have a function to set these pointers to a specific object.

```
void Timetable::setLecture(Lecture& lecture){
    while ((lecture.getDuration()) -1 > 0){
        scheduledLectures[lecture.getDayScheduled()][(lecture.getHourScheduled())+1] = &lecture;
    }
}
```

the compiler returns no errors for this, but when its running, it seems that the pointers remain NULLs.
i am sure the error is inside the setter function (and almost sure that its a grammar mistake) but i cannot find the solution for that.
whats wrong in here?

thank you

Comment: Don't be a [three star programmer](http://wiki.c2.com/?ThreeStarProgrammer).

Comment: You might want to make a [mcve]. The problem is not in the code posted.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `vector` (or `std::array`) of pointers or `shared_ptr`s (or `unique_ptr`s depending on how your lifetimes are arranged) instead of a 2D array of pointers that you manage yourself.  Save yourself the trouble of managing the memory and lifetimes of your objects manually.

```
class TimeTable {
    vector<vector<shared_ptr<Lecture>>> scheduledLectures;
};

Timetable::Timetable(int hours) 
        : TimetableBase(hours), 
        scheduledLectures(5, vector<shared_ptr<Lecture>>(5)) {}

void Timetable::setLecture(std::shared_ptr<Lecture> lecture){
    while ((lecture->getDuration()) -1 > 0) { // not sure what this does
        scheduledLectures[lecture->getDayScheduled()][(lecture->getHourScheduled())+1] = lecture;
    }
}
```

You can test whether a `shared_ptr` is null like follows

```
auto s_ptr = std::shared_ptr<int>{}; // null
// either assign it to a value or keep it null
if (s_ptr) { 
    // not null
}
```

---

If you are managing the memory of the `Lecture` objects elsewhere then just use a 2D vector of pointers and trust your code

```
class TimeTable {
    vector<vector<Lecture*>> scheduledLectures;
};

Timetable::Timetable(int hours) 
        : TimetableBase(hours), 
        scheduledLectures(5, vector<Lecture*>(5)) {}

void Timetable::setLecture(Lecture& lecture){
    while ((lecture.getDuration()) -1 > 0) { // not sure what this does
        scheduledLectures[lecture.getDayScheduled()][(lecture.getHourScheduled())+1] = &lecture;
    }
}
```

Comment: please don't use vector of vectors as a 2d array. It's not hard to make a flat 2d array class.

Comment: @Sopel no, its not overkill to use a `vector` to abstract away managing memory for a flat 2d array.  If you think so, then use an `std::array`

Comment: 1. Vector of vectors has unnecesary overhead of more allocations (also possibly worse locality) 2. It is not obvious that the code doesnt use it as a jagged array. 3. You dont need the dynamic part of the vectlr

Comment: @Sopel Overhead in terms of what?  Such claims are only be justified if there is a dire requirement for minimizing allocations at all costs.  Vector allocation are O(1) amortized, because vectors double when they need to reallocate memory, so the cost is not that much over a large sequence of insertions.  When you talk about fewer elements, its not that much at all because well there are fewer allocations.  If you absolutely cannot have allocations, then an `std::array` works well.

Comment: Regarding 2, you can use vectors even when you dont need jagged arrays.  Regarding 3, then use an `std::array`, the user using `new` indicates that the `5` is not set in stone.  OP's code is dynamically allocating memory, and the number of allocations when switching to a vector implementation are likely exactly the same

Comment: You cant use std array in this case

Comment: @Sopel Why not?

Comment: Because the size of it has to be known at compile time

Comment: Also you can compare smart poiners with nullptr_t directly

Comment: @Sopel that was in response to you saying `3. You dont need the dynamic part of the vector`  The need for dynamic allocations is why I suggested using a vector in the first place.  If you are suggesting variable length arrays then take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887097/why-arent-variable-length-arrays-part-of-the-c-standard

Comment: Im not suggesting vlas

Comment: @Sopel Comparing a pointer to `nullptr` explicitly is seen as bad style by a lot of people (myself included) as opposed to just `if (ptr)` or `if (!ptr)`, then what were you suggesting as a justification for not using `std::vector` when you said `You dont need the dynamic part of the vector`?

Comment: @Sopel Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/381621/using-arrays-or-stdvectors-in-c-whats-the-performance-gap

Comment: if I use a vector for this, how can I call the setLecture function? before that I was calling it with a reference to a lecture object. now it seems like i have to convert this pointer somehow