# stackoverflow Exception in C++ incrementing counter in while loop

Tags: c++, sql-server, exception, odbc

I keep searching for insight into what's wrong with this but can't find it; it is probably something dumb that I'm overlooking.  I hope you can see it!

I have a while loop in a C++ pgm where I am loading SQL Server data using ODBC into 3 different arrays (1 for each column).  If I increment the array counter outside the while loop (above in the code, commented out), of course it doesn't advance the array entries, but it does not blow up.  If I move the increment (rowNum++) into the while loop (as shown), I get a stackoverflow exception.  Can anyone give me a hint please?  Thanks much!

```
    else {
        short iptMKTNUM;
        short iptDAYNUM;
        float iptPX;
        int rowNum = 0;
        //rowNum++;
        while (SQLFetch(SQLStatementHandle) == SQL_SUCCESS) {
            SQLGetData(SQLStatementHandle, 1, SQL_C_DEFAULT, &iptMKTNUM, sizeof(iptMKTNUM), NULL);
            SQLGetData(SQLStatementHandle, 2, SQL_C_DEFAULT, &iptDAYNUM, sizeof(iptDAYNUM), NULL);
            SQLGetData(SQLStatementHandle, 3, SQL_C_FLOAT,   &iptPX,     sizeof(iptPX),     NULL);
            MktNum[rowNum] = iptMKTNUM;
            DayNum[rowNum] = iptDAYNUM;
            Price[rowNum] = iptPX;
            cout << "Mkt/Day/Px IS " << iptMKTNUM << " " << iptDAYNUM << " " << iptPX << endl;
            cout << "Mkt/Day/Px IS " << MktNum[rowNum] << " " << DayNum[rowNum] << " " << Price[rowNum] << endl;
            cout << "rowNum is " << rowNum << endl;
            rowNum++;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Post [mcve]. Your code snipped is not relevant to the issue. Probably you access out of array bounds.

Answer (score 1):

How did you allocate your arrays `MktNum`, `DayNum`, `Price`? This important part you held back, as you are not allowed to access the arrays out of their range.

Probably you should use `vectors` instead of arrays and then use `push_back` to append the values. The number of rows you can get from the size of the vectors.

```
 vector<short> MktNum;
 vector<short> DayNum;
 vector<float> Price;
 while (SQLFetch(SQLStatementHandle) == SQL_SUCCESS) {
        SQLGetData(SQLStatementHandle, 1, SQL_C_DEFAULT, &iptMKTNUM, sizeof(iptMKTNUM), NULL);
        SQLGetData(SQLStatementHandle, 2, SQL_C_DEFAULT, &iptDAYNUM, sizeof(iptDAYNUM), NULL);
        SQLGetData(SQLStatementHandle, 3, SQL_C_FLOAT,   &iptPX,     sizeof(iptPX),     NULL);
        MktNum.push_back(iptMKTNUM);
        DayNum.push_back(iptDAYNUM);
        Price.push_back(iptPX);
        cout << "Mkt/Day/Px IS " << iptMKTNUM << " " << iptDAYNUM << " " << iptPX << endl;
        cout << "Mkt/Day/Px IS " << MktNum.back() << " " << DayNum.back() << " " << Price.back() << endl;
        cout << "rowNum is " << (-1 + MktNum.size()) << endl;
    }
```

Comment: I finally got thru it.  The problem was my array sizes.  I was overflowing them.  They are about 10.5 million entries each.  I found a message that said to either define the arrays as "in file scope", or simply preface with the "static" parm.  I did the latter and it solved it.  The load is fast, maybe 10 seconds to fill from SQL Server.  Do you think I should try the vector approach, or just move on?  THANKS for your advice by the way!

Comment: Depends on your use case. `vector`s are the preferred way.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/381621/using-arrays-or-stdvectors-in-c-whats-the-performance-gap You should try to avoid handling memory by yourself with new and delete when there is a solution which takes care of it..