# Do 2D+ (e.g., 3D) vectors cause a performance hit?

Tags: c++, arrays, stdvector

I'm working on a synth and I have some code that's going slower than I'd like.  I've narrowed down the culprit to some nested for loops which iterate over a three-dimensional vector of floats.  Given that this part of my code is the current bottle neck, I'd like to optimize it as best as I can.

My current understanding of two-dimensional C arrays is that they are really just one long linearly-nested array with some fancy syntax.

```
int* myArray[3][3];
pseudoSetEntriesToRowNum(myArray);
for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
  cout << myArray[i];
}
// output: 000111222
```

As for vectors, (when one-dimensional) the performance seems to be widely sufficient (*[Using arrays or std::vectors in C++, what's the performance gap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/381621/using-arrays-or-stdvectors-in-c-whats-the-performance-gap)*) with issues arising more from resizing than accessing/setting.  But when two-dimensional, my understanding would suggest that the linearly-nested optimization is lost, and that for each dimension a pointer is being followed.

```
vector<vector<int>> myVector = pseudoMake2dVectorWithRowNumAsEntries(3, 3);
int* myArray = &(myVector[0][0]);
for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
  cout << myArray[i];  // this should not be okay
}
// (my guess of) output: 0,0,0, BAD_ACCESS * 6
```

Am I even thinking about this correctly?  And, if I am, would the implication be that 2D+ dimensional vectors are not good for time-sensitive operations?  And if 2D+ dimensional vectors are not ideal, what are some good alternatives?

Comment: It depends on how you put together the 2D array.  [See this as an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21943621/how-to-create-a-contiguous-2d-array-in-c/21944048#21944048).

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ please read the questions before marking them as duplicates.  I linked the "duplicate" in my question, and this is an entirely different one having to do with multi-dimensional arrays.

Comment: Your guess is correct. The three inner vectors do not necessarily occupy consecutive areas of memory because the outer array is just 3 pointers..You can always serialize 2D+ arrays into 1D by defining order of traversal. E.g. `[i][j]`->`[i*<inner size>+j]`.

Comment: @SephReed Number of dimensions isn't relevant, the answers from the marked duplicate still apply.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I'm getting mixed information.  Quimby says multi-dimensional vectors do not necessarily serialize.  Would you mind linking to the specific part of your linked question which covers this subject?

Comment: @SephReed Multi dimensional nested `std::vector` won't guarantee contiguous memory blocks, and thus are CPU cache unfriendly for some certain operations. Hence the discussion about performance hits.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54974157/4808079  Better than nothing.