# How to initialize array later when using private object variable (after initializing the object)

Tags: c++, arrays, oop, multidimensional-array

I want to first initialize "dummy" array when i create a object. I have this in private part of my class.

```
// Initialize dummy array when object is initialized.
int* matrix_[0][0];
```

Then i want later to initialize new array to replace the dummy one (one that has actual size). I have method for this in my class:

```
void set_map_size(int width, int height) {
    int* pm[width][height];
    matrix_ = pm;
}
```

So the problem is when I try to initialize this array after the creation of the object. I want other methods / other objects to have access to this array.

Maybe I should have pointer? Initialize pointer as nullptr when object is created and then change pointer to point to array?

Comment: `int* matrix_[0][0];` doesn't look right, is this standard? Shouldn't you use `malloc` or `new` instead of a local automatic variable in that function? To avoid all these, consider using `std::vector` if you can

Comment: It probably doesn't work. I was just trying to illustrate what I would like to achieve. @Ayxan

Comment: @Ayxan `int* matrix_[0][0]` isn't right, it declares a 0 length 2d array of pointers. But malloc should pretty much never be used in c++, and raw new only very rarely has a place.

Comment: I would like to have there something has place holder so that i could replace it later with actual 2d array when i know the size. At the initialization of the object I don't yet know the size of the array I want to use.

Comment: I'd keep things simple if I were you, and go with @Ayxan s suggestion of using std::vector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right way to do this in C++ is to use vectors.

```
vector<vector<int>> matrix_;
```

You may then dynamically resize your matrix

```
void set_map_size(int width, int height) {
    matrix_.resize(height); 
    for (auto &x : matrix_) 
       x.resize(width);
}
```

Because arrays are of fixed size and variable length array are not standard C++ (even if some compilers accept it).

Comment: The thing is whenever you need a variable array of some sort in C++, the answer is always `std::vector`

Comment: @George [Vectors have very similar performance](https://stackoverflow.com/a/381656/10147399) and handling a dynamically allocated array is enough of a pain that unless you absolutely need that infinitesimal performance gain in your high-performance library code, you should go with `std::vector`

Comment: @George If performance is at stake, the 2D vector should be flattened to a 1D vector. This could make a significant difference. If it would nevertheless appear that there would be a performance issue, you could still use a pointer to [`data()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/data) in the time critical section.  But do this only if the performance issue was really confirmed by measurement, because "*premature optimization is the root of all evil*"